# Cannot find mysql.sock

Tags: mysql, macos, sockets, installation

I just had to re-install mysql and I am having a problem starting it up.  It cannot find the socket (mysql.sock).  The problem is that neither can I.  In my Mac OS X 10.4 terminal, I type: `locate mysql.sock`, and I get back `/private/tmp/mysql.sock`.  It makes sense that the socket file exist in that location, but it actually does not.

1. How can I find the socket file?
2. If locate is returning a false location, it must have some sort of memory and probably indexes.  How can I refresh that index?

Comment: `/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/var/mysql/mysql.sock`

Comment: [Refer to this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65137289/6521116)

Answer (score 148, accepted):

to answer the first part of your question:

run

```
% mysqladmin -p -u <user-name> variables
```

and check the 'socket' variable

Comment: I would totally change this answer to the correct one if I could. If only I had known this sooner!

Comment: Ran `mysqladmin variables`. What to do when `error: 'Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (2)'`? :)

Comment: I'm getting the same error as @afEkenholm and haven't been able to find a solution.  I ran `sudo find / -name mysql.sock` from the root directory and was unable to find mysql.sock anywhere on the system.  I installed MySQL using the 64 bit dmg file for Mac OS 10.7.  Running Mavericks currently.

Comment: @b_dubb I am the same with your situation, How did you solved your issues?

Comment: @MeganZhou I cannot recall.  I might have tried reinstalling from the DMG file.  Sorry I can't be of more help.

Comment: To quickly look up the socket param without all the others do:  mysqladmin variables | grep socket

Comment: Everything in this answer and comments gives the same `error: 'Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (2)'`. Creating the file in /tmp/mysql.sock gives the same error, no matter what the permissions are. I'm using macOS Big Sur with brew mysql@5.6.

Answer (score 62):

This solved my problem

```
mysql_config --socket
```

**UPDATE**

mysql_config can tell us where the file mysql.sock should be, but in my case the file didn't exist. So, I've deleted my.cnf:

```
sudo rm -rf /etc/my.cnf
```

And then restarted mysql:

```
brew services restart mysql
```

The file was created and mysql is now running well.

Comment: That command tells you where the mysql.sock is which answer the question

Comment: This command does not tell you where the file is. It tells you where mysql is looking for it: the configuration setting for the --socket.

Comment: I dont have
 `ls: /etc/my.cnf: No such file or directory`
May be I have  to create it first?

Comment: if you do not have file at `/etc/my.cnf` try looking at `/usr/loca/etc/my.cnf` - @Abhi

Comment: I found `/usr/loca/etc/my.cnf`  and remove it. but it doesn't help me to recreate the sock file

Answer (score 24):

This found it for me:

```
netstat -ln | grep mysql
```

Mac OSX

Answer (score 20):

The socket file should be created automatically when the MySQL daemon starts.

If it isn't found, most likely the directory which is supposed to contain it doesn't exist, or some other file system problem is preventing the socket from being created.

To find out where the file should be, use:

```
% mysqld --verbose --help | grep ^socket
```

Comment: Or mysql --verbose --help | grep ^socket

Comment: @Ondrej surely that tells you where the _client_ thinks it's looking?  The point of running `mysqld` is that it should tell you where the _server_ actually put it!

Comment: on my xampp installation I couldn't find the daemon so tried without it and it worked :) ... what happened behind the scenes I have no clue of ...

Answer (score 12):

My problem was also the mysql.sock-file.

During the drupal installation process, i had to say which database i want to use
but my database wasn't found

```
mkdir /var/mysql
ln -s /tmp/mysql.sock /var/mysql/mysql.sock
```

the system is searching mysql.sock but it's in the wrong directory

all you have to do is to link it ;)

it took me a lot of time to google all important informations but it took me even hours to find out how to adapt , but now i can present the result :D

ps: if you want to be exactly you have to link your `/tmp/mysql.sock-file` (if it is located in your system there too) to the directory given by the php.ini (or php.default.ini) where `pdo_mysql.default_socket= ...`

Comment: After you changed in php.ini the `pdo_mysql.default_socket` you need to restart the webserver for the changes to load `sudo apachectl restart`

Answer (score 7):

I got the exact path using:

```
netstat -ln | grep -o -m 1 -E '\S*mysqld?\.sock'
```

Since this only returns the path and doesn't require any input you could potentially use it in a shell script.

MySQL must be currently running on your machine for this to work. Works for MariaDB too.

Comment: Great answer! This actually finds the location of the socket, unlike any of the other answers.

Answer (score 2):

```
$ mysqladmin variables | grep sock
```

Try this instead, this will output the demanded result, getting rid of unrelated info.

Answer (score 2):

The original questions seems to come from confusion about a) where is the file, and b) where is it being looked for (and why can't we find it there when we do a locate or grep).    I think Alnitak's point was that you want to find where it was linked to - but grep will not show you a link, right?  The file doesn't live there, since it's a link it is just a pointer.  You still need to know where to put the link.

my sock file is definitely in /tmp   and the ERROR I am getting is looking for it in /var/lib/  (not just /var)  I have linked to /var and /var/lib now, and I still am getting the error "Cannot connect to local MySQL server through socket 'var/lib/mysql.sock' (2)".

Note the (2) after the error....  I found on another thread that this means the socket might be indeed attempted to be used, but something is wrong with the socket itself - so to shut down the machine - completely - so that the socket closes.  Then a restart should fix it.  I tried this, but it didn't work for me (now I question if I restarted too quickly?  really?)  Maybe it will be a solution for someone else.

Answer (score 2):

I'm getting the same error on Mac OS X 10.11.6:

`ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (2)`

After a lot of agonizing and digging through advice here and in related questions, none of which seemed to fix the problem, I went back and deleted the installed folders, and just did `brew install mysql`.

Still getting the same error with most commands, but this works:

`/usr/local/bin/mysqld`

and returns:

> /usr/local/bin/mysqld: ready for connections.
>
> Version: '5.7.12'  socket: '/tmp/mysql.sock'  port: 3306  Homebrew

Answer (score 0):

To refresh the locate's database I ran

```
/usr/libexec/locate.updatedb
```

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find mysql socket at all so reinstalled mysql server(all tables and phpmyadmin settings were preserved). Here are the commands:

1) Install

> sudo apt-get install mysql-server

2) Follow terminal configuration steps

> sudo mysql_secure_installation

3) Check status: (Should return "Active: active (running)")

> systemctl status mysql.service

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately none of the above have worked in my case. But finally I found solutions.

To find where is mysql.sock file, simply open xampp manager, select MySQL and click on Configure on the right. On the config panel click Open Conf File, and simply search for mysql.sock by pressing the CMD+F shortcut.

In my case, the owner of the mysql.sock was changed, and I had to change it back to root admin with: chmod root:admin mysql.sock

After that the database had been accessed.

Answer (score -4):

I can't help with question #1, but to refresh `locate`'s file database, run:

```
updatedb
```