# MySQL connection not working: 2002 No such file or directory

Tags: php, mysql, connection

I'm trying to set up WordPress. I have Apache and MySQL running, and the accounts and database are all set up. I tried to make a simple connection:

```
<?php
    $conn = mysql_connect('localhost', 'USER', 'PASSWORD');
    if(!$conn) {
        echo 'Error: ' . mysql_errno() . ' - ' . mysql_error();
    }
?>
```

And I always get this:

> Error: 2002 - No such file or
>   directory

What file or directory could it be talking about?

I'm on a OS X Snow Leopard, using the built-in Apache. I installed MySQL using the x86_64 dmg.

UPDATE: I found that the socket is at /tmp/mysql.sock, so In php.ini, I replaced all occurrences of the wrong path with that.

Comment: please paste the output of `/etc/init.d/mysql start` if you're on a debian base distro. if failed, check `/etc/my.cnf` file for the correct mysql socket file path.

Comment: solved same problem on OS X with XAMPP using "127.0.0.1" in place of "localhost".

Comment: Related: [I've got `PDOException: SQLSTATE(2002) No such file or directory](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/99446/1908)

Answer (score 106, accepted):

If you use Linux: the path to the mysql.sock file is wrong. This is usually because you are using (LAMPP) XAMPP and it isn't in /tmp/mysql.sock

Open the php.ini file and find this line:

```
mysql.default_socket
```

And make it

```
mysql.default_socket = /path/to/mysql.sock
```

Comment: if you're not sure , try /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock as the new path to the socket.

Comment: WordPress works now! I actually remember going through a tutorial saying to do this, but read somewhere that you don't need to on Snow Leopard or something like that.

Comment: Hmm. Maybe they meant Leopard or Tiger. In any case, have fun with WordPress!

Comment: Note you may need to set mysqli.default_socket = /path/to/mysql.sock if connecting with mysqli

Comment: Solved my issue. Thanks! Other issue was I thought my php.ini file was in /etc/php.ini but it was actually /usr/local/lib/php.ini (On Mac OS X with PHP 5.4 installed from source.)

Comment: The default socket location for a stock MySQL install is /tmp/mysql.sock.

Comment: sometime it will be at /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock (Ubuntu)

Comment: "The hostname localhost has a special meaning. It is bound to the use of Unix domain sockets. It is not possible to open a TCP/IP connection using the hostname localhost you must use 127.0.0.1 instead." - http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.connections.php. So basically something is not working with connecting to the Unix domain sockets that allow `localhost` to work and TCP/IP is working so changing it to the TCP/IP address `127.0.0.1` will work.

Comment: I had to add 'unix_socket'   => '/Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock' to config/database.php

Comment: In Ubuntu, maybe it's here: /opt/lampp/var/mysql/mysql.sock.
But it's not working for me.

Comment: You Saves me Time to solving this type f**ky error.

Comment: Do docker containers also contain a `mysql.sock` file?

Answer (score 207):

I had a similar problem and was able to solve it by addressing my mysql with `127.0.0.1` instead of `localhost`.

This probably means I've got something wrong in my hosts setup, but this quick fix get's me going for right now.

Comment: you just saved me some precious time.

Comment: I checked my hosts file and found a line with `code`127.0.0.1 localhost`code`. Which makes me curious to why connecting through localhost did not work. If someone could enlighten me I would be happy.

Comment: This is because the mysql.default_socket in php.ini is wrong.  Run "php -i | grep mysql.default_socket"

Comment: This worked for me, I'm on el Capitan w/ mysql 5.7 installed via homebrew. I was trying a WP install and when I changed "localhost" to "127.0.0.1" it was able to connect.

Comment: "The hostname localhost has a special meaning. It is bound to the use of Unix domain sockets. It is not possible to open a TCP/IP connection using the hostname localhost you must use 127.0.0.1 instead." - http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.connections.php. So basically something is not working with connecting to the Unix domain sockets that allow `localhost` to work and TCP/IP is working so changing it to the TCP/IP address `127.0.0.1` will work.

Comment: After hours of trying to fix it... Worked like a charm! Thank you... But how do I fix my hosts (on Mac) now ?

Comment: Or it means your on windows, where localhost isn't guaranteed to be a resolvable hostname...

Comment: WoW! you saved me, bro!

Comment: where to make this change, please name the file too?

Comment: This should be one of the first things to try when you got such error.

Answer (score 42):

This is for **Mac OS X** with the **native installation of Apache HTTP** and **custom installation of MySQL**.

The answer is based on @alec-gorge's excellent response, but since I had to google some specific changes to have it configured in my configuration, mostly Mac OS X-specific, I thought I'd add it here for the sake of completeness.

### Enable PHP5 support for Apache HTTP

Make sure the PHP5 support is enabled in `/etc/apache2/httpd.conf`.

Edit the file with `sudo vi /etc/apache2/httpd.conf` (enter the password when asked) and uncomment (remove `;` from the beginning of) the line to load the **php5_module** module.

```
LoadModule php5_module libexec/apache2/libphp5.so
```

Start Apache HTTP with `sudo apachectl start` (or `restart` if it's already started and needs to be restarted to re-read the configuration file).

Make sure that `/var/log/apache2/error_log` contains a line that tells you the php5_module is enabled - you should see `PHP/5.3.15` (or similar).

```
[notice] Apache/2.2.22 (Unix) DAV/2 PHP/5.3.15 with Suhosin-Patch configured -- resuming normal operations
```

### Looking up Socket file's name

When MySQL is up and running (with `./bin/mysqld_safe`) there should be debug lines printed out to the console that tell you where you can find the log files. Note the hostname in the file name - `localhost` in my case - that may be different for your configuration.

The file that comes after `Logging to` is important. That's where MySQL logs its work.

```
130309 12:17:59 mysqld_safe Logging to '/Users/jacek/apps/mysql/data/localhost.err'.
130309 12:17:59 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /Users/jacek/apps/mysql/data
```

Open the `localhost.err` file (again, yours might be named differently), i.e. `tail -1 /Users/jacek/apps/mysql/data/localhost.err` to find out the socket file's name - it should be the last line.

```
$ tail -1 /Users/jacek/apps/mysql/data/localhost.err
Version: '5.5.27'  socket: '/tmp/mysql.sock'  port: 3306  MySQL Community Server (GPL)
```

Note the `socket:` part - that's the socket file you should use in `php.ini`.

There's another way (some say an easier way) to determine the location of the socket's file name by logging in to MySQL and running:

```
show variables like '%socket%';
```

### Configuring PHP5 with MySQL support - /etc/php.ini

Speaking of php.ini...

In `/etc` directory there's **/etc/php.ini.default** file. Copy it to **/etc/php.ini**.

```
sudo cp /etc/php.ini.default /etc/php.ini
```

Open `/etc/php.ini` and look for **mysql.default_socket**.

```
sudo vi /etc/php.ini
```

The default of `mysql.default_socket` is `/var/mysql/mysql.sock`. You should change it to the value you have noted earlier - it was `/tmp/mysql.sock` in my case.

Replace the `/etc/php.ini` file to reflect the socket file's name:

```
mysql.default_socket = /tmp/mysql.sock
mysqli.default_socket = /tmp/mysql.sock
```

### Final verification

Restart Apache HTTP.

```
sudo apachectl restart
```

Check the logs if there are no error related to PHP5. No errors means you're done and PHP5 with MySQL should work fine. Congrats!

Comment: This answer helps

Comment: This answer is crap. It has nothing to do with the question being asked and is basically only a m(acos)amp tutorial, which - if good - is even more wasted if put here and not at a place where people who actual search for setting up an amp stack on macos are looking at. Regarding the question being asked: this answer doesnt explain shit on why the error happens and why php tries to connect via the socket instead of the hostname instead, although that is passed to `mysql_connect`, which is the *actual* problem of the original question and not a generic misconception of installing software.

Comment: @ohcibi I wrote _"I thought I'd add it here for the sake of completeness."_ and thought it'd be enough (and given the upvotes a few people liked it). I like your idea of making the answer easier to find, but dunno how. Could you share your thoughts and help me...again? Thanks!

Comment: @JacekLaskowski in general: write a blog post and comment a link to it to the accepted/most upvoted response with the same intention you had here ("add it for the sake of completeness"). But in this very thread I don't even see a reason to post that link. The OP said that he is using macOS but this problem has nothing at all to do with any operating system but with mySQL'sway of interpreting `localhost`. Nobody looking for help on setting up xamp on macos will get here by googling. Hence I used the term 'crap'. This thread has nothing to do at all with macos but with mysql only (not even php).

Answer (score 18):

Restarting the mysql server might help. In my case, restarting the server saved a lot of time.

```
service mysql restart
```

P.S.- use `sudo service mysql restart` for non-root user.

Comment: It's so great when the simple solution actually works.

Answer (score 17):

Replacing 'localhost' to '127.0.0.1' in config file (db connection) helped!

Comment: but why it should be helped?

Comment: "Replacing 'localhost' to '127.0.0.1'" or 127.0.0.1 to actual MySQL server address i.e. u55151.mysql.someserver.eu.

Answer (score 10):

First, ensure MySQL is running. Command: mysqld start

If you still cannot connect then:
What does your /etc/my.cnf look like? (or /etc/msyql/my.cnf)

The other 2 posts are correct in that you need to check your socket because 2002 is a socket error.

A great tutorial on setting up LAMP is: http://library.linode.com/lamp-guides/centos-5.3/index-print

Comment: The installer didn't put a my.cnf file, however there is a `/usr/local/mysql/mysql-test/include/default_my.cnf`, should I copy that as my.cnf to `/etc` ?

Comment: yes, but you may find that you need to modify it some latter.

Answer (score 10):

Expanding on [Matthias D's answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17350870/2570775) I was able to resolve this **2002 error** on both MySQL  and MariaDB with exact paths using these commands:

First get the **actual path** to the MySQL socket:

```
netstat -ln | grep -o -m 1 '/.*mysql.sock'
```

Then get the **PHP path**:

```
php -r 'echo ini_get("mysql.default_socket") . "\n";'
```

Using the **output of these two commands**, link them up:

```
sudo ln -s /actualpath/mysql.sock /phppath/mysql.sock
```

If that returns `No such file or directory` you just need to create the path to the PHP mysql.sock, for example if your path was `/var/mysql/mysql.sock` you would run:

```
sudo mkdir -p /var/mysql
```

Then try the **sudo ln** command again.

Answer (score 8):

Not that it helps you much, but in the [recent versions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/error-messages-client.html) (and even [less recent](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/error-messages-client.html)) of MySQL, error code 2002 means “Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket [name-of-socket]”, so that might tell you a bit more.

Comment: On OSX 10.9.x with MySQL 5.5.38 installed from source, I was getting this error.  This tip was correct: it a socket issue even though mysqli_connect_errno() and mysqli_connect_error()) were saying the 2002 file not found message.  I was able to resolve this by editing my /etc/php.ini and setting mysql.default_socket AND mysqli.default_socket to correct socket value (since my application was using mysqli for connections)

Answer (score 6):

I'd check your php.ini file and verify the mysql.default_socket is set correctly and also verify that your mysqld is correctly configured with a socket file it can access. Typical default is "/tmp/mysql.sock".

Comment: Ok, It says `/var/mysql/mysql.sock`, but that path doesn't exist.

Answer (score 6):

I encountered this problem too, then  i modified 'localhost' to '127.0.0.1',it works.

Answer (score 6):

in my case I have problem with mysqli_connect. 
when I want to connect 
    `mysqli_connect('localhost', 'myuser','mypassword')`
 
 mysqli_connect_error() return me this error "No such file or directory"

this worked for me
`mysqli_connect('localhost:3306', 'myuser','mypassword')`

Comment: This worked well for me; it was the change I needed to load Armchair Analysis's American football statistics package into an OS X local Mysql installation.  Thanks!

Comment: glad to hear that :)

Answer (score 4):

The error 2002 means that MySQL can't connect to local database server through the socket file (e.g. `/tmp/mysql.sock`).

To find out where is your socket file, run:

```
mysql_config --socket
```

then double check that your application uses the right Unix socket file or connect through the TCP/IP port instead.

Then double check if your PHP has the right MySQL socket set-up:

```
php -i | grep mysql.default_socket
```

and make sure that **file exists**.

Test the socket:

```
mysql --socket=/var/mysql/mysql.sock
```

If the Unix socket is wrong or does not exist, you may symlink it, for example:

```
ln -vs /Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock /var/mysql/mysql.sock
```

or correct your configuration file (e.g. `php.ini`).

To test the [PDO](http://php.net/PDO) connection directly from PHP, you may run:

```
php -r "new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;port=3306;charset=utf8;dbname=dbname', 'root', 'root');"
```

Check also the configuration between Apache and CLI (command-line interface), as the configuration can be differ.

> It might be that the server is running, but you are trying to connect using a TCP/IP port, named pipe, or Unix socket file different from the one on which the server is listening. To correct that you need to invoke a client program (e.g. specifying `--port` option) to indicate the proper port number, or the proper named pipe or Unix socket file (e.g. `--socket` option).

See: [Troubleshooting Problems Connecting to MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/problems-connecting.html)

---

Other utils/commands which can help to track the problem:

- `mysql --socket=$(php -r 'echo ini_get("mysql.default_socket");')`
- `netstat -ln | grep mysql`
- `php -r "phpinfo();" | grep mysql`
- `php -i | grep mysql`
- Use XDebug with `xdebug.show_exception_trace=1` in your `xdebug.ini`
- On OS X try `sudo dtruss -fn mysqld`, on Linux debug with `strace`
- Check permissions on Unix socket: `stat $(mysql_config --socket)` and if you've enough free space (`df -h`).
- Restart your MySQL.
- Check [`net.core.somaxconn`](https://serverfault.com/q/408528/130437).

Answer (score 4):

by using `127.0.0.1` insteady of `localhost` solve the problem

Answer (score 3):

Make sure your local server (MAMP, XAMPP, WAMP, etc..) is running.

Comment: In addition to this, if you are using MAMP on MacOS (obviously!) you also get this error if you access your site immediately after waking your Mac from sleep. The solution, of course, is to simply wait and try again. :-)

Answer (score 2):

May be I am late to answer this, but what solved my problem was to install the mysql-server

```
sudo apt-get install mysql-server
```

after spending more than 5 hours I found this solution which helped me to proceed.
I hope this would help someone if the top answers won't help them

Answer (score 1):

**Digital Ocean** MySql 2002-no-such-file-or-directory

Add this end of file `/etc/mysql/my.cnf`

```
[mysqld]
innodb_force_recovery = 1
```

**Restart MySql**

`service mysql restart`

Comment: The right thing is to restart the MySQL service

Answer (score 1):

First check MySQL server is running or not. if running then check socket path by login to MySQL through command line.

> mysql -uUSER -pPASSWORD

then

> show variables like 'socket';

You'll find path of mysql socket which you can use further in connection string like below:

> $conn = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'USER', 'PASSWORD', 'path of
> socket file');

If MySQL is not running. Then Please share error logs which you are getting to troubleshoot further.

Comment: This didn't solve my problem, but it led me to the solution: Since I run DBngin, I do not have a socket, so running `mysql -u...` yielded socket not found. That's when I realized I needed to use 127.0.0.1 for my connection.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem.
Basically here the problem is there are probably two instances of mysql running.
A) One running at /etc/init.d 
B) Lamp being installed at /opt/lamp 
Solution :
Step 1 :- Find all mysql running instances using commnad "find / | grep mysqld"
Step 2 :- Shutdown the services running at /etc/init.d using service mysql stop

Step 3 :- Restart your Lamp services using /opt/lamp/lamp restart

You should be good to go :)

Answer (score 0):

On a Mac, before doing all the hard work, simply check your settings in `System Preferences > MySQL`.  More often than not, I've experienced the team running into this problem since `The MySQL Server Instance is stopped`.

Click the `Start MySQL Server` button, and magic will happen.

Answer (score 0):

Im using PHP-FPM or multiple php version in my server. On my case i update mysqli value since there is not mysql default socket parameter  :

```
mysqli.default_socket
```

to :

```
mysql.default_socket = /path/to/mysql.sock
```

thanks to @Alec Gorge

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. My socket was eventually found in /tmp/mysql.sock. Then I added that path to php.ini. I found the socket there from checking the page "Server Status" in MySQL Workbench. If your socket isn't in /tmp/mysql.sock then maybe MySQL Workbench could tell you where it is? (Granted you use MySQL Workbench...)

Answer (score 0):

I've installed MySQL using installer. In fact, there was no data directory alongside 'bin' directory.

So, I **manually created** the 'data' directory under "C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0". And it worked (changing the root password following steps suggested on https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-windows-excerpt/5.7/en/resetting-permissions-windows.html.

Answer (score -2):

enable and start mariadb service

sudo systemctl enable mariadb.service

sudo systemctl start mariadb.service