# PHP Laravel Migrate Creation from Composer Error

Tags: php, migration, laravel-4, composer-php

I installed a laravel project from GitHub and I put it into the localhost and I installed composer from terminal.After installation,I want to run:

```
php artisan migrate:install
```

in my laravel project file

but I always getting this type of error in my terminal:

```
  [PDOException]                                    
  SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory
```

How can I overcome this issue?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Starting with Zend Tutorial - Zend\_DB\_Adapter throws Exception: "SQLSTATE\[HY000\] \[2002\] No such file or directory"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2412009/starting-with-zend-tutorial-zend-db-adapter-throws-exception-sqlstatehy000)

Comment: is it possible to show us the app/config/database.php file?