# Update PHP 5.3 to 5.5 error SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have migrate an app from a localserver with XAMMP to a hosting service, I'm using some functions of PHP 5.5 than are not supported by 5.3, My hosting had PHP 5.3, I configured it to 5.5 then this happens when trying to connect to mysql database with PDO

```
SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory
```

What do I have to configure to correctly connect to MYSQL and make my app run

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2412009/starting-with-zend-tutorial-zend-db-adapter-throws-exception-sqlstatehy000

Maybe this helps

Comment: Thank you very much, I Solved the problem configuring the php.ini file.