# "SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory" error when migrating table in Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-artisan, homestead

I am getting the following error when I try to migrate a table in Laravel 5 using the "php artisan migrate" command:

> 'SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory' in . . .
>   /vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connectors/Connector.php:47

My .env file includes the default settings as follows:

```
DB_HOST=localhost
DB_DATABASE=homestead
DB_USERNAME=homestead
DB_PASSWORD=secret
```

My database.php file lists mysql as the default database connection, homestead is listed as the database in my homestead.yaml file, and homestead is one of the tables listed when I access mysql and use the `show databases;` command.

Any thoughts about what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: Did u try php artisan migrate --env=urenv ?

Comment: I just had this issue and it was because I in the wrong terminal window. I was trying to run the command on my local machine rather than the vagrant box.

Answer (score 10):

try `127.0.0.1` instead of `localhost` in your `.env` file. It works for me :)

Answer (score 3):

Add mysql.sock path in database.php file like below example

```
'unix_socket' => '/Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock',
```

Eample

```
'mysql' => [
        'driver' => 'mysql',
        'unix_socket' => '/Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock',
        'host' => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
        'port' => env('DB_PORT', '8889'),
```

[PDOException SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20723803/pdoexception-sqlstatehy000-2002-no-such-file-or-directory)

Answer (score 2):

Change `localhost` as your `DATABASE_HOST` in the `.env` file, change it to `127.0.0.1`, and after that run `php artisan config:clear` and then run `php artisan migrate:install` again.

Or if your problem is not solved, use these changes in your .env files:

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=localhost
DB_PORT=3306
```

Then in Database.php add folder location:

```
'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', '/Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock'),
```

Finally, try:

```
php artisan config:clear
php artisan migrate:install
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be an issue with the socket file. Please let me know if this helps [Starting with Zend Tutorial - Zend_DB_Adapter throws Exception: "SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2412009/starting-with-zend-tutorial-zend-db-adapter-throws-exception-sqlstatehy000)

Answer (score 0):

Okay, this is might be a special case to me however I had this issue.

I moved my files from a Laragon based server to a mamp based server on a different machine. I had this error for days and I only received this error when running `php artisan migrate` and not when loading the page. When loading the page i received table not found which is understandable as the table isn't there.

After quite some time I just though of running `composer update` and then it fixed the error and worked for me. Not sure if this helps anyone but I came back to this post in case it somehow does.