# cakephp bake SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory

Tags: php, cakephp

I followed the CakePHP tutorial and till now everything worked fine(newly added articles are shown in the db). But now that I tried to "bin/cake bake model users" I get the following error message: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory in [/opt/lampp/htdocs/MyApp/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Database/Driver.php, line 92].
I found this solution here: [SQLSTATE HY000 2002 while running bake command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30941506/sqlstate-hy000-2002-while-running-bake-command) . But this does not seem to work on linux(Ubuntu). Any help would be appreciated.

Full Error:

```
Exception: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory in [/opt/lampp/htdocs/MyApp/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Database/Driver.php, line 92] 2018-12-06 11:28:03 Error: [PDOException] SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory in /opt/lampp/htdocs/MyApp/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Database/Driver.php on line 92 Stack Trace:
#0 /opt/lampp/htdocs/MyApp/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Database/Driver.php(92): PDO->__construct('mysql:host=loca...', 'root', '', Array)
#1 /opt/lampp/htdocs/MyApp/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Database/Driver/Mysql.php(106): Cake\Database\Driver->_connect('mysql:host=loca...', Array)
#2 /opt/lampp/htdocs/MyApp/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Database/Schema/BaseSchema.php(45): Cake\Database\Driver\Mysql->connect()
#3 /opt/lampp/htdocs/MyApp/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Database/Dialect/MysqlDialectTrait.php(63): Cake\Database\Schema\BaseSchema->__construct(Object(Cake\Database\Driver\Mysql))
#4 /opt/lampp/htdocs/MyApp/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Database/Schema/Collection.php(52): Cake\Database\Driver\Mysql->schemaDialect()
#5 /opt/lampp/htdocs/MyApp/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Database/Schema/CachedCollection.php(42): Cake\Database\Schema\Collection->__construct(Object(Cake\Database\Connection))
#6 /opt/lampp/htdocs/MyApp/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Database/Connection.php(391): Cake\Database\Schema\CachedCollection->__construct(Object(Cake\Database\Connection), true)
#7 /opt/lampp/htdocs/MyApp/vendor/cakephp/bake/src/Shell/Task/ModelTask.php(1052): Cake\Database\Connection->getSchemaCollection()
#8 /opt/lampp/htdocs/MyApp/vendor/cakephp/bake/src/Shell/Task/ModelTask.php(1006): Bake\Shell\Task\ModelTask->_getAllTables()
#9 /opt/lampp/htdocs/MyApp/vendor/cakephp/bake/src/Shell/Task/ModelTask.php(213): Bake\Shell\Task\ModelTask->listAll()
#10 /opt/lampp/htdocs/MyApp/vendor/cakephp/bake/src/Shell/Task/ModelTask.php(131): Bake\Shell\Task\ModelTask->getAssociations(Object(Cake\ORM\Table))
#11 /opt/lampp/htdocs/MyApp/vendor/cakephp/bake/src/Shell/Task/ModelTask.php(114): Bake\Shell\Task\ModelTask->getTableContext(Object(Cake\ORM\Table), 'users', 'Users')
#12 /opt/lampp/htdocs/MyApp/vendor/cakephp/bake/src/Shell/Task/ModelTask.php(101): Bake\Shell\Task\ModelTask->bake('Users')
#13 /opt/lampp/htdocs/MyApp/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Console/Shell.php(532): Bake\Shell\Task\ModelTask->main('users')
#14 /opt/lampp/htdocs/MyApp/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Console/Shell.php(525): Cake\Console\Shell->runCommand(Array, false, Array)
#15 /opt/lampp/htdocs/MyApp/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Console/CommandRunner.php(342): Cake\Console\Shell->runCommand(Array, true)
#16 /opt/lampp/htdocs/MyApp/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Console/CommandRunner.php(164): Cake\Console\CommandRunner->runShell(Object(Bake\Shell\BakeShell), Array)
#17 /opt/lampp/htdocs/MyApp/bin/cake.php(12): Cake\Console\CommandRunner->run(
```

Array)

## 18 {main}

Comment: Have you installed Cakephp using composer?

Comment: It seems like if you remove the `vendor` directory and perform a `composer install` the problem will be fixed

Comment: I just had the same issue, with CakePHP 3.8 in a Xampp stack on Linux.   Cause was the wrong version of PHP being run (my system-wide install of PHP at `/usr/bin/php`).   Solution: added the path `/opt/lampp/bin` to my PATH and all was well. :)

Answer (score 10):

On my case the problem was fixed by changing app/config.php, simply change datasource host from "localhost" to "127.0.0.1"

```
    'Datasources' => [
    'default' => [
        'className' => 'Cake\Database\Connection',
        'driver' => 'Cake\Database\Driver\Mysql',
        'persistent' => false,
        'host' => '127.0.0.1',...
```

Answer (score 1):

Follow the below points

1. Your cake-php isn't connected to any local database, visit
   pagesController from browser to see if its connected to database,if
   not you need to configure in config/app.php with database name and
   credential.
2. You are in cake-php project directory, try to hit the same "bin\cake
   bake model users" in windows ,for linux use "bin/cake bake model
   users".

Reply to this thread if issues not resolved

Answer (score -1):

Try changing datasource host from `localhost` to `127.0.0.1`

Comment: This is effectively duplicating [an existing answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61939396/761202). If there's something missing from an answer, please propose an edit, otherwise please use votes/comments if you agree with it or it helped you :).