# cakephp bake console error Exception: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory in

Tags: php, cakephp

I'm trying to follow the CakePHP tutorial for tags and users here.: https://book.cakephp.org/3/en/tutorials-and-examples/cms/tags-and-users.html

However, I keep encountering this error for bin/cake bake model users and bin/cake bake template users.

bin/cake bake controller users works fine.

I tried changing the database host to 'host' => '127.0.0.1' but it still shows the same error.

Does anyone know how to solve this? I'm using CakePHP in vagrant environment on Mac OS. Thank you!

This is what the error says for both model users and template users command.

```
Exception: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory in [/home/vagrant/app/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Database/Driver.php, line 93]
2024-03-20 09:01:03 Error: [PDOException] SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory in /home/vagrant/app/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Database/Driver.php on line 93
Stack Trace:
#0 /home/vagrant/app/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Database/Driver.php(93): PDO->__construct('mysql:host=loca...', 'my_app', 'secret', Array)
#1 /home/vagrant/app/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Database/Driver/Mysql.php(105): Cake\Database\Driver->_connect('mysql:host=loca...', Array)
#2 /home/vagrant/app/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Database/Schema/BaseSchema.php(44): Cake\Database\Driver\Mysql->connect()
#3 /home/vagrant/app/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Database/Dialect/MysqlDialectTrait.php(62): Cake\Database\Schema\BaseSchema->__construct(Object(Cake\Database\Driver\Mysql))
#4 /home/vagrant/app/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Database/Schema/Collection.php(51): Cake\Database\Driver\Mysql->schemaDialect()
#5 /home/vagrant/app/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Database/Schema/CachedCollection.php(41): Cake\Database\Schema\Collection->__construct(Object(Cake\Database\Connection))
#6 /home/vagrant/app/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Database/Connection.php(399): Cake\Database\Schema\CachedCollection->__construct(Object(Cake\Database\Connection), true)
#7 /home/vagrant/app/vendor/cakephp/bake/src/Shell/Task/ModelTask.php(1096): Cake\Database\Connection->getSchemaCollection()
#8 /home/vagrant/app/vendor/cakephp/bake/src/Shell/Task/ModelTask.php(1050): Bake\Shell\Task\ModelTask->_getAllTables()
#9 /home/vagrant/app/vendor/cakephp/bake/src/Shell/Task/ModelTask.php(213): Bake\Shell\Task\ModelTask->listAll()
#10 /home/vagrant/app/vendor/cakephp/bake/src/Shell/Task/ModelTask.php(131): Bake\Shell\Task\ModelTask->getAssociations(Object(Cake\ORM\Table))
#11 /home/vagrant/app/vendor/cakephp/bake/src/Shell/Task/ModelTask.php(114): Bake\Shell\Task\ModelTask->getTableContext(Object(Cake\ORM\Table), 'users', 'Users')
#12 /home/vagrant/app/vendor/cakephp/bake/src/Shell/Task/ModelTask.php(101): Bake\Shell\Task\ModelTask->bake('Users')
#13 /home/vagrant/app/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Console/Shell.php(531): Bake\Shell\Task\ModelTask->main('users')
#14 /home/vagrant/app/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Console/Shell.php(524): Cake\Console\Shell->runCommand(Array, false, Array)
#15 /home/vagrant/app/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Console/CommandRunner.php(384): Cake\Console\Shell->runCommand(Array, true)
#16 /home/vagrant/app/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Console/CommandRunner.php(162): Cake\Console\CommandRunner->runShell(Object(Bake\Shell\BakeShell), Array)
#17 /home/vagrant/app/bin/cake.php(12): Cake\Console\CommandRunner->run(Array)
#18 {main}
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you so much.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [cakephp bake SQLSTATE\[HY000\] \[2002\] No such file or directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53650659/cakephp-bake-sqlstatehy000-2002-no-such-file-or-directory)

Comment: If that doesn't help, then try Google `cakephp Error: [PDOException] SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory` and you will find several posts about it (I just checked).