# Laravel Connection Refused Error

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, connection-refused

I'm aware this is a repeat question, but none of the solutions online seem to be working for me.

I'm trying to add authentication to a laravel 5 project (using `make:auth`)
Whenever I try to 'register', I get a `SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused` error.

The responses online have been to change localhost to 127.0.0.1 and vise-vera, but that isn't working for me.

Any idea anyone?
Thanks (I'm on OSX, if that makes a difference at all)

```
.env
DB_HOST=localhost
DB_DATABASE=test
DB_USERNAME=test
DB_PASSWORD=
```

```
database.php
'mysql' => [
            'driver'    => 'mysql',
            'host'      => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
            'database'  => env('DB_DATABASE', 'test'),
            'username'  => env('DB_USERNAME', 'test'),
            'password'  => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
            'charset'   => 'utf8',
            'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
            'prefix'    => '',
            'strict'    => false,
        ],
```

Comment: Please check your socket path as noted in this thread: [stackoverflow thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2412009/starting-with-zend-tutorial-zend-db-adapter-throws-exception-sqlstatehy000)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try adding mysql port in your database.php

```
        'driver'    => 'mysql',
        'host'      => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
        'port'      => '33060',//your mysql port
```

Answer (score 8):

If you are using MAMP be sure to add the unix_socket key with a value of the path that the mysql.sock resides in MAMP.

```
'mysql' => array(
'driver'    => 'mysql',
'host'      => 'localhost',
'unix_socket'   => '/Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock',
'database'  => 'database',
'username'  => 'root',
'password'  => 'root',
'charset'   => 'utf8',
'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
'prefix'    => '',
),
```

Comment: This should be the right answer! Thanks. It worked on High Sierra