# Getting Error in web application developed in zend framework

Tags: zend-framework

I have one website develop in zend framework, I have just transfered it to new host server,I am getting this error in my website

> "Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message
>   'SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory' in
>   /home/mi229844/solway.ge/library/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php:129
>   Stack trace: #0
>   /home/mi229844/solway.ge/library/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php(129):
>   PDO->__construct('mysql:host=loca...', 'mi229844_sol', 'hxjz58pm',
>   Array) #1 "

Thankyou.

Comment: Can you please show me your application.ini file ?

Comment: The `SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory` error usually means that connecting to the database failed. It could be because of any number reasons e.g. the database server is down, it hasn't been started, the pdo connection is configured incorrectly.

Comment: Also, see possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/q/2412009/934739.