# Phalcon Developer Tools Model creation doesn't work

Tags: php, sql, mamp, phalcon

I'm using a MAMP stack with Phalcon and trying to use the Developer Tools. However if I try to create a model I get the following error:

`ERROR: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory`

I checked the installation itself, the sql settings of the project and the socket values (mysql, mysqli, pdo_mysql). I have no further clue about how to fix this.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you have problem with connection to your DB. Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2412009/starting-with-zend-tutorial-zend-db-adapter-throws-exception-sqlstatehy000) - it suggests to use DB IP instead of hostname.

Answer (score 0):

Check if you can login to your database using console's command: `mysql -u USERNAME -p`. Add parameter `-p` only when you are using password for your user. Use credentials stored in your Phalcon config (assuming that you actually have one, if not - create it). [More details](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/connecting.html) If it doesn't work - solving this problem should solve model creating issue.