# MariaDB my.cnf SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002]

Tags: mysql, mariadb

Could someone check my **my.cnf** please?
What's wrong with it? I used tools.percona.com to generate this cnf.

```
[mysqld]
bind-address = ::ffff:127.0.0.1
local-infile=0
datadir=/var/lib/mysql
socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
symbolic-links=0

# MyISAM #
key-buffer-size                = 32M
myisam-recover                 = FORCE,BACKUP

# SAFETY #
max-allowed-packet             = 16M
max-connect-errors             = 1000000

# BINARY LOGGING #
log-bin                        = /var/lib/mysql/mysql-bin
expire-logs-days               = 14
sync-binlog                    = 1

# CACHES AND LIMITS #
tmp-table-size                 = 32M
max-heap-table-size            = 32M
query-cache-type               = 0
query-cache-size               = 0
max-connections                = 500
thread-cache-size              = 50
open-files-limit               = 65535
table-definition-cache         = 4096
table-open-cache               = 4096

# INNODB #
innodb-flush-method            = O_DIRECT
innodb-log-files-in-group      = 2
innodb-log-file-size           = 512M
innodb-flush-log-at-trx-commit = 1
innodb-file-per-table          = 1
innodb-buffer-pool-size        = 20G

[mysqld_safe]
log-error=/var/log/mariadb/mariadb.log
pid-file=/var/run/mariadb/mariadb.pid

#
# include all files from the config directory
#
!includedir /etc/my.cnf.d
```

Here is error message:

> ERROR: Zend_Db_Adapter_Exception: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file
>   or directory

This one works fine:

```
[mysqld]
bind-address = ::ffff:127.0.0.1
local-infile=0
datadir=/var/lib/mysql
socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
symbolic-links=0

[mysqld_safe]
log-error=/var/log/mariadb/mariadb.log
pid-file=/var/run/mariadb/mariadb.pid

#
# include all files from the config directory
#
!includedir /etc/my.cnf.d
```

Thanks

PS: I tried just this, but same error:

```
[mysqld]
bind-address = ::ffff:127.0.0.1
local-infile=0
datadir=/var/lib/mysql
socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
# Disabling symbolic-links is recommended to prevent assorted security risks
symbolic-links=0
# Settings user and group are ignored when systemd is used.
# If you need to run mysqld under a different user or group,
# customize your systemd unit file for mariadb according to the
# instructions in http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Systemd
innodb-flush-method            = O_DIRECT
innodb-log-files-in-group      = 2
innodb-log-file-size           = 512M
innodb-flush-log-at-trx-commit = 1
innodb-file-per-table          = 1
innodb-buffer-pool-size        = 20G


[mysqld_safe]
log-error=/var/log/mariadb/mariadb.log
pid-file=/var/run/mariadb/mariadb.pid

#
# include all files from the config directory
#
!includedir /etc/my.cnf.d
```

Comment: Try commenting this line: `log-bin = /var/lib/mysql/mysql-bin`

Comment: @Hackerman, thanks, I tied, but still the same error :(
I also tried comment `log-bin, expire-logs-days, sync-binlog` .

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2412009/starting-with-zend-tutorial-zend-db-adapter-throws-exception-sqlstatehy000 it's not related ?

Comment: @Blag, yes but my first my.cnf and second have the same path to socket. 
First one working fine, after adding innodb-*, ... I'm starting getting this error. Php and my.cnf have the same path to socket.

Comment: Do you have 32GB of RAM?

Comment: Why 32GB config is set to 20GB, then I set to 15GB, then to 10GB same problem. I have 24GB