# Yii Console Command cant connect to database

Tags: php, yii, console

I'm trying to set up a console command in Yii, and can echo out a return to the command fine, but i can't get the command to do anything useful. Im trying to get it to insert a record, but i cannot seem to connect to my database - despite the fact my actual application works perfectly - with the same connect details.

I'm assuming the console.php config file is incorrect - but am at a loss. Here's my console config file

```
// This is the configuration for yiic console application.
// Any writable CConsoleApplication properties can be configured here.
return array(
    'basePath'=>dirname(__FILE__).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'..',
    'name' => 'My Console Application',

    // preloading 'log' component
    'preload'=>array('log'),
    //import
    'import' => array(
        'application.models.*',
        'application.components.*',
        'application.extensions.*',
    ),
    // application components
    'components'=>array(
        'db' => array(
            'connectionString' => 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=xxx',
            'emulatePrepare' => true,
            'username' => 'xxx',
            'password' => 'xxx',
            'charset' => 'utf8',
            'tablePrefix' => 'sys_',
            'class' => 'CDbConnection'
        ),
        'log'=>array(
            'class'=>'CLogRouter',
            'routes'=>array(
                array(
                    'class'=>'CFileLogRoute',
                    'levels'=>'error, warning',
                ),
            ),
        ),
    ),
    'params' => array(
        'keyword' => 'test',
    ),
);
```

I can't even get my console command to write to the log, again, despite my actual application writes fine. here my command

```
class NewSysCommand extends CConsoleCommand {

    public function test() {
        echo "\nI've ran a sys test command successfully!\n\n";
        Yii::log('Command test to write to log', 'error');
    }

    public function captureIssueResponse(){
        Yii::log('captureIssueResponse write to log', 'warning');

        //Create our booking
        $issueResponse = new IssueResponses();
        $issueResponse->issue_id = 40;
        $issueResponse->ticket_id = "1111";
        $issueResponse->response = "new response from command line 1";
        $issueResponse->save();
    }

    public function run($args) {
        self::test();
        self::captureIssueResponse();
        return 0;
    }

}
```

and this is the error i get when trying to run my command in console using 'protected/yiic newSys'

```
I've ran a sys test command successfully!

exception 'CDbException' with message 'CDbConnection failed to open the DB connection: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory' in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/framework/db/CDbConnection.php:382
Stack trace:
#0 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/framework/db/CDbConnection.php(330): CDbConnection->open()
#1 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/framework/db/CDbConnection.php(308): CDbConnection->setActive(true)
#2 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/framework/base/CModule.php(387): CDbConnection->init()
#3 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/framework/base/CApplication.php(450): CModule->getComponent('db')
#4 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/framework/db/ar/CActiveRecord.php(634): CApplication->getDb()
#5 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/framework/db/ar/CActiveRecord.php(2361): CActiveRecord->getDbConnection()
#6 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/framework/db/ar/CActiveRecord.php(411): CActiveRecordMetaData->__construct(Object(IssueResponses))
#7 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/framework/db/ar/CActiveRecord.php(79): CActiveRecord->getMetaData()
#8 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/MyApplication/sysadmin/protected/commands/NewSysCommand.php(23): CActiveRecord->__construct()
#9 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/MyApplication/sysadmin/protected/commands/NewSysCommand.php(52): NewSysCommand->captureIssueResponse()
#10 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/framework/console/CConsoleCommandRunner.php(71): NewSysCommand->run(Array)
#11 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/framework/console/CConsoleApplication.php(92): CConsoleCommandRunner->run(Array)
#12 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/framework/base/CApplication.php(180): CConsoleApplication->processRequest()
#13 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/framework/yiic.php(33): CApplication->run()
#14 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/MyApplication/sysadmin/protected/yiic.php(7): require_once('/Applications/X...')
#15 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/MyApplication/sysadmin/protected/yiic(4): require_once('/Applications/X...')
```

Can anyone see what i'm doing wrong?

Comment: the config looks fine, Are you able to connect to the DB using another method like PHPMyAdmin, or HeidiSQL. it could be that the user does'nt have the proper privileges

Comment: Yes, not only does PHPMyAdmin work fine, but my main application which used the same database credentials / privledges works fine too

Comment: If you search on the exact mysql Error : ```SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory``` you get the following result http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2412009/starting-with-zend-tutorial-zend-db-adapter-throws-exception-sqlstatehy000 so properly there is something wrong with your PHP config

Comment: @TimvanderGaag - good shout - the answer was to change localhost to 127.0.0.1! Thanks mate

Answer (score 2):

You should change the host to 127.0.0.1 or try to use MySQL socket like so:

```
mysql:host=localhost;dbname=xxxx;unix_socket=/Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock
```

This is working well for MAMP, but possibly for XAMPP as well.