# PHP Socket PDO SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, websocket

### Introduction

For the past couple of days I’ve been messing about with PHP web sockets, in an attempt to retrieve some information in real-time for the user about the various different people connected.

I’m on Ubuntu, running the latest version of XAMPP (located under `/opt/lampp/`), the web socket I run using PHP which I’ve installed using `apt-get install php`. This opens a socket with no problem whatsoever.

The problem I’m facing has to do with establishing a connection to the database from the web socket with a little help from PDO. Whenever I attempt to establish the connection to the database located on `localhost`, I get the following error message:

```
SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory
```

Since PHP and my MySQL server isn’t aware of one another, considering MySQL is run through the instance of XAMPP and the server is run using the version of PHP (which is the same as the one as for XAMPP) I’ve installed using `apt-get`, one might think that this is the cause of problems. But shouldn’t the server be reachable as long as you have the correct username and password to the server configuration?

### Research

I’ve been doing quite some research on the subject, and have found multiple potential solutions for the problem, but neither one appears to do the job. For example, [on this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2412009/starting-with-zend-tutorial-zend-db-adapter-throws-exception-sqlstatehy000), it is suggested that you can solve this error by doing some witchery to your server software, as well as PHP—I’ve tried this with to apparent success.

On other questions, it’s instead suggested that you change this DSN PDO setup:

```
$dsn = "mysql:host=$host;port=$port;dbname=$name;charset=$charset";
```

To instead of using "localhost" for the host, you stick with `127.0.0.1`—as a matter of fact, I can’t even connect unto my server if I were to do this. Doing this, my XAMPP gets stuck in some form of endless loop. A minute or so after changing from `127.0.0.1`, back to `localhost`, it starts working again.

I can’t remember where, but I also remember seeing somebody saying it’s not at all doable (connecting to MySQL from a PHP socket), which I’d find extremely strange.

Some people also seem to suggest switching to [Node.js](https://nodejs.org/en/) for handling real-time connections, but I’d very much like to keep it all PHP if possible.

### Furthermore

**I’m probably just being a complete moron** (I was ;-)), but if anybody can point me in the right direction it would be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to specify the path of the socket 
example:

```
$dsn = 'mysql:dbname=testdb;unix_socket=/path/to/socket';
```

Try to search the file mysql.sock inside the /opt/lamp

Comment: There’s a `mysql.so` file, but no file named `mysql.socket`. The `mysql.so` file isn’t human readable. By socket example, in the DSN string, I assume you mean the path to the socket file which I can’t seem to locate. In the case of you meaning I’m supposed to specify the path to my PHP server socket, I get an error saying "Connection refused" upon specifying this.

Comment: The `mysql.so` is the compiled PHP extension. This provides the MySQL API for PHP. Of course, this is not human readable.

Comment: I take what I said back—my apologies. There was a `mysql.sock` file located under `/opt/lampp/var/mysql/mysql.sock`, which when it was added to the `unix_socket` suddenly made everything work! I’d suggest you edit your answer @daheda to include this part of the solution for anyone who might come across this question in the future!