# MySQL: Error #2002

Tags: php, mysql, linux, ubuntu, zend-server

I'm trying to install an opensource software on my local and I'm running zendserver on linux ubuntu.

I created the database and provided a correct user and password.
But as soon as I click on submit button I get a MySQL 2002 error saying:

```
(2002) No such file or directory
```

I tried to restart apache2 but still I get the same error after I have restarted apache2.

How can I resolve this Mysql error?

Comment: Try the below link All the best :)

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1676688/php-mysql-connection-not-working-2002-no-such-file-or-directory/24371396#24371396

Answer (score 0):

1. You don't have permissions to access the directory /var/lib/mysql/whatever.sock because mysql is the owner of the folder 
   or
2. /path/whatever.sock doesn't exist.

You can try this though [Linux specific, but what other operating systems are there?] 
Go to /etc/my.cnf and change/add the lines:

[mysqld] 
datadir=/var/lib/mysql 
socket=/tmp/mysql.sock 
[client] 
socket=/tmp/mysql.sock

This way the client and server use the same socket and it's in a public directory.