# Magento gives SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory in cpanel

Tags: mysql, linux, magento, cpanel

My magento website gives this error when I visit the site. my server is cpanel centos 6.4 -When I do graceful server reboot it comes back but after some time I got same error again. Which is:

```
SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory
```

**/dev/mapper/VolGroup00-root** partition almost full. maybe that's why.

```
/dev/mapper/VolGroup00-home /home   19% (79,541,260 of 458,391,760) 

/usr/tmpDSK /tmp    3% (10,794 of 495,844)  

/dev/mapper/VolGroup00-root /   100% (19,613,172 of 20,642,428)
```

I don't know how to solve this. My server provider is not answering me.

Thanks

Comment: Check if you have big logs. You can check the disk usage by files with `du -h` in the specific dir hierarchy.

Comment: I have cleaned all the logs and other big files.

Comment: And how is it now? Also, check if there are any processes overloading the server. You can do it with `ps -ef`.

Comment: With root full, mysql can't create mysql socket... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1676688/php-mysql-connection-not-working-2002-no-such-file-or-directory