# MySQL error 2002 when use INSERT INTO

Tags: php, mysql, mysql-error-2002

I have a problem with mysql. When I execute this, that give me an error: No such file or directory 2002, but SELECT query work perfect and print typ on the screen. What can I solve this problem?

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("db4free.net","****","****","*****");
if (mysqli_connect_errno($con))
{
   echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

$username = $_GET['username'];
$password = $_GET['password'];
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT Typ FROM Uzytkownik where Login='$username' and Haslo='$password'");

$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
$data = $row[0];
if($data){
echo $data;
}

$que =  "INSERT INTO Uzytkownik VALUES ('10','tr','t','a')";
if( !mysql_query($que) ) {
     echo  "ERROR!!: ".mysql_error().mysql_errno() ;
}
mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Result of this:

```
testERROR!!: No such file or directory2002
```

**EDIT** Sorry, I pasted wrong code, but it was already changed

Comment: I do not see where your 'INSERT INTO' call is in your code.

Comment: Modify your question and include the omitted INSERT INTO. How do you expect us to help without even knowing the problem ?

Comment: Refer to this and check if it solves the problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1676688/php-mysql-connection-not-working-2002-no-such-file-or-directory

Comment: @gurudeb: I'm not using xampp(localhost) but db4free.net and it doesn't work.

Comment: Sorry, I pasted wrong code, but it was already changed

Comment: You are mixing `mysql_*` and `mysqli_*` functions. Use only `mysqli_*`.

Comment: Your code is **very** vunerable towards SQL injection. `login.php?username=admin' --` would think I'm admin without knowing the password. Also, don't store passwords in cleartext.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot mix `mysqli_*` functions with `mysql_*` functions.

replace this:

```
if( !mysql_query($que) ) {
     echo  "ERROR!!: ".mysql_error().mysql_errno() ;
}
```

with

```
if( !mysqli_query($con, $que) ) {
     echo  "ERROR!!: ".mysqli_error($con) ;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the insert query you should tell which columns you're inserting into.

```
$que = "INSERT INTO Uzytkownik(col1, col2, col3, col4) VALUES ('10','tr','t','a')";
```

Also note that most of your queries are vulnerable to [sql-injections](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection), you should use [prepared statements](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php) to protect your code.

Example: Your select query looks like this:

```
"SELECT Typ FROM Uzytkownik where Login='$username' and Haslo='$password'".
```

If I were a user I could get in without using a password, by ending the sql statement within the username or within the password, I could drop the table and I could even drop the entire database if I were a blackhat in a bad mood.

Using prepared statements means that instead of using user-input-provided values you replace the user inputs with `VALUES(?, ?)` and then you can bind parameters that will then be executed and replace the placeholders.

Using [PDO](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) allows you to use named paramters, you should take a look at that.

Also note that you're mixing `mysql_*` and `mysqli_*` which are not the same library of functions, stick to one (otherwise it simply won't work) and `mysqli_*` is way better `since mysql_*` is deprecated. This could be causing your problem.

Comment: Vulnerable to SQL injections with hard coded values? That's a new one to me.

Comment: The query is unsafe and should be changed accordingly, doesn't mean that I have to do it for him.

Comment: The query is completely safe. There is no way it can be used for an SQL injection since there are no values provided by a user.

Comment: Sorry, I did not make my point entirely clear. The insert statement itself is safe but I highly assume that this statement is for testing and once he gets that working he'll start inserting user input. Same goes with the select query, which is unsafe.

Comment: You are right regarding the select query. But then you should use the select query as an example, and you should post it as a comment, since it doesn't answer the question in any way.

Comment: Good point. And I misread it since I overly assumed that his edit was stating that he was using same kind of a connection but that was obviously way out of context.