# MDB2 Failure to Connect to MySQL on OSX Mavericks

Tags: php, mysql, mdb2

Configuration:

```
Mac OS X 10.9.3
PHP 5.4.24 (default)
MySQL 5.6.17
pear list:
    MDB2              2.4.1   stable
    MDB2_Driver_mysql 1.4.1   stable
    PEAR              1.9.4   stable
```

I have a database in place on localhost and it's accessible with a particular account and password:

```
% mysql -u stacks -p password
mysql> use redseaexp_radtags;
Database changed
mysql> ^D
```

But:

```
% php -a
php > require_once("/usr/local/share/pear/MDB2.php");
php > $dsn = 'mysql://stacks:password@localhost/redseaexp_radtags';
php > $options = array();
php > $dbh = MDB2::connect($dsn, $options);
php > echo($dbh->getMessage() . "\n");
MDB2 Error: connect failed
php > echo($dbh->getUserInfo() . "\n");
connect: [Error message: No such file or directory]
[Native code: 2002]
[Native message: No such file or directory]
 ** mysql(mysql)://stacks:xxx@localhost/redseaexp_radtags
php > ^D
```

I don't see any issues with this code, but I could be missing something; the same errors occur if I leave off '/redseaexp_radtags'.

Is there perhaps a software compatibility issue?

Comment: mdb2, really? Oh my...

Comment: Does connecting via command line localhost work with `mysql -u stacks -ppassword -h localhost redseaexp_radtags` ?

Comment: Re: “Oh my…" Is there a problem with using MDB2?

Comment: Re: “Does connecting via command line localhost work”  Yes:  mysql> show tables;  
+-----------------------------+  
| Tables_in_redseaexp_radtags |  
+-----------------------------+  
| alleles                     |  
| batches                     |  
| catalog_alleles             |  
| catalog_annotations         |  
| catalog_genotypes           |  
| catalog_snps                |  
| catalog_tags                |  
| chr_index                   |  
| fst                         |  
| ...                         |  
+-----------------------------+  
21 rows in set (0.00 sec)

Comment: OK, found the answer: the file or directory that's missing is the socket file. Read more here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1676688/php-mysql-connection-not-working-2002-no-such-file-or-directory