# Lumen: Migrate - No such file or directory

Tags: laravel, lumen

I have a naked installation of the newsest Lumen version.

**php artisan migrate**

results in the following error:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP - MySQL connection not working: 2002 No such file or directory](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1676688/php-mysql-connection-not-working-2002-no-such-file-or-directory)

Comment: @Maraboc I actually disagree. While the underlaying issue is the same, Lumen as a framework has a specific way of handling this. Nothing in that post addresses where in Lumen you would have to make that change.

Answer (score 4):

```
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
```

instead of

DB_HOST=localhost

```
solved the problem!
```

Answer (score 0):

Issue is less to due with Lumen and more to do with your environment. That specific PDO error indicates that your connection factory has a bad reference to the unix socket location.

Lumen is smart, however, and knows that this can be a problem. Open your database configuration and give it a default socket path:

```
'mysql' => [
     //....
     'unix_socket'   => '/Full/Path/To/mysql/mysql.sock',
]
```