# php artisan migration error after loosing database from phpmyadmin

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5, phpmyadmin

By Mistake My mac got shutdown and when i opened it the database was gone from phpmyadmin
I have tried 
php artisan migrate it throws following error

```
No such file or directory (SQL: select * from information_schema.tables where table_schema = phpdemo and table_name = migrations).
```

I tried replacing localhost from 127.0.0.1 at DB_HOST in .env file . but no luck
I am using xampp , php version 7.2.7

Please help me

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4219970/warning-mysql-connect-2002-no-such-file-or-directory-trying-to-connect-vi and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1676688/php-mysql-connection-not-working-2002-no-such-file-or-directory might give you some help

Comment: Or this one, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20723803/pdoexception-sqlstatehy000-2002-no-such-file-or-directory, this one has like 500 votes and is laravel migration related, check the answer with 500+ votes, not the accepted one

Answer (score 1):

firstly
you need to check if the mysql service is running, i find this [How to check if MySQL server is working or not?](https://serverfault.com/questions/558731/how-to-check-if-mysql-server-is-working-or-not)

```
sudo service mysql status
```

then, check the .env file, and check if the database is created, if not, you can create it and then run

```
php artisan migrate
```

If still not working, maybe you'll need to add manually the migrations table, and all the data, that table ony have 3 columns: id, migration, batch (in my case, laravel 5.5), the id is an autoincrements, the migrations has the name of the migration file(for example 2014_10_12_000000_create_users_table) and all the batch columns in my projects has the 1

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try manually create empty database with name `phpdemo` and then run `php artisan migrate` again