# MySQL socket missing

Tags: mysql, sockets, vps

I bought a VPS server(Ubuntu operating system). I installed mysql-server and phpmyadmin. It works well, but now when I try access phpMyAdmin page I got this message:

```
#2002 No such file or directory <br /> The server is not responding (or the local server's socket is not correctly configured).
```

And in putty this error:

```
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'
```

How to restore missing socket?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1676688/mysql-connection-not-working-2002-no-such-file-or-directory

Comment: You probably have a corrupt config file

Comment: I deleted all mysql files or folders, and use this command: `sudo apt-get purge mysql`, now all is corrupted!

Comment: I want to remove totally mysql and reinstall it, how to do this(`sudo apt-get purge mysql`, return an error)

Comment: It's sometimes easier to just delete and recreate the server with a LAMP stack, if you messed up badly. Fixing configuration files, when you obviously are not a server manager, will probably be harder.

Comment: Reinstalling mysql is a multi step process. Especially if you have old configuration files that will survive a purge.

Comment: I think I will reset the server!