# Laravel project not working after moving from Windows to Linux

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have a local Laravel installation that works fine on Windows, but when I move the project to Linux, I get this error:

> Illuminate \ Database \ QueryException (2002) SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002]
>   No such file or directory (SQL: select * from `users` where `email` =
>   bk@gmail.com and `status` = 1 limit 1)

Previous exceptions:

> SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory (2002)
>   SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory (2002)

What could be the reason?

Note: Linux system is newly set up.

Comment: Have you made sure that the permissions are set correctly on the storage and logs folder?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PDOException SQLSTATE\[HY000\] \[2002\] No such file or directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20723803/pdoexception-sqlstatehy000-2002-no-such-file-or-directory)

Comment: your project is not setup properly. did you run composer ,migration and generate key etc ?

Comment: @Petay87 i have give 777 permission

Comment: How did you move it from Windows to Linux, by copying folder or with Git?

Comment: @Niklesh Raut I have run these all commonds
-- composer update
-- php artisan cache:clear
-- php artisan view:clear
-- php artisan route:clear
-- php artisan clear-compiled
-- php artisan config:cache

-- php artisan migrate:refresh 
-- php artisan migrate:refresh --seed 
-- php artisan db:seed

-- composer dump-autoload

Comment: Did you run all those commands on the Linux server too?

Comment: @Elisha Senoo  I have copy project from window and move it on Ubuntu var/www/html folder

Comment: Yes I have run these all commonds

Comment: There should be more that error include the whole stack trace and error messages

Comment: Also might help https://stackoverflow.com/a/1676741/487813

Comment: Did you setup .env file in your project on linux.

Comment: Do you get the error when you run 'php artisan migrate:refresh --seed'?

Answer (score 1):

I have clone project from github fresh and run

-- composer update
-- php artisan cache:clear
-- php artisan view:clear
-- php artisan route:clear
-- php artisan clear-compiled
-- php artisan config:cache
-- php artisan config:clear

-- php artisan migrate:refresh
-- php artisan migrate:refresh --seed
-- php artisan db:seed

-- composer dump-autoload

-- php artisan key:generate

and it work fine for me
Thank all for your valuable time