# MySQL error: SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'test'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Tags: php, mysql

I'm actually making a form in PHP with MVC2. In my model, I need to connect to a local MySQL database. I do this with PDO. Here is my dsn :

```
mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test-heia;charset=utf8mb4', "test", "test"
```

But when I try to access my model through Chrome, I got this error (with PDOException) :

> **SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'test'@'localhost' (using password: YES)**

I'm sure of the user/password. I also tried with root user, but it doesn't seems to work.

It's not like the proposed answer, because it's on a web page :)

Could you please help me ? Thank you in advance :)

Comment: does the user test have permission to access test db?

Comment: You should update your title since it isn't the same error message as in your question.

Comment: @MasivuyeCokile yes he has

Comment: @MagnusEriksson ? it's the same error message ^^

Comment: Can you access the database with the same user/pass via the command line?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'bill'@'localhost' (using password: YES)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10299148/mysql-error-1045-28000-access-denied-for-user-billlocalhost-using-passw)

Comment: You should also make sure that the user is allowed to connect using `localhost`. You could try `127.0.0.1` instead and see if that works better. They are not always interchangeable.

Comment: @aynber yes I can access through the command line

Comment: @MagnusEriksson ok, I'll try that tomorrow, ty :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved the problem. The path to the socket of MySQL wasn't enabled ([see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1676688/mysql-connection-not-working-2002-no-such-file-or-directory)). Once I put it, it worked.

Thank's all for the answers ! :)

Answer (score 0):

```
define('DBHOST', 'localhost');
define('DBUSER', 'test');
define('DBPASS', 'test');
define('DBNAME', 'test');

try {
    $bd= new PDO('mysql:host='.DBHOST.';dbname='.DBNAME,DBUSER,DBPASS);
}catch(Exception $e)
 {
    die('Erreur : '.$e->getMessage());
 }
```

Try it with that

Comment: There's no real difference between your code and the OP's code.

Comment: There is no difference, because he said he wanted to connect PDO and what I did is pdo.

Comment: Ty, Il try this tomorrow :)

Comment: Works like magic, thanks for the tip. I had the same issue with different production servers...