# Using MySQL and PHP with Google Maps - markers not loading

Tags: php, google-maps, google-maps-markers

I am a beginner in php. I have used this google documentation: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/mysql-to-maps

First I created a XML table with markers using a PHP script. The code from google docs did not work for me (could not connect to my database), but with code below could I create an output that at least looks like its in the right format: http://www.desemdelen.nl/XML.php

```
<?
require ("phpsqlajax_dbinfo.php");

function parseToXML($htmlStr)
{
    $xmlStr = str_replace('<', '&lt;', $htmlStr);
    $xmlStr = str_replace('>', '&gt;', $xmlStr);
    $xmlStr = str_replace('"', '&quot;', $xmlStr);
    $xmlStr = str_replace("'", '&#39;', $xmlStr);
    $xmlStr = str_replace("&", '&amp;', $xmlStr);
    return $xmlStr;
}

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error)
{
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

$sql = "SELECT id, name, address, lat, lng, type FROM markers";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

header("Content-type: text/xml");

// Start XML file, echo parent node
echo '<markers>';
$ind = 0;
// Iterate through the rows, printing XML nodes for each
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
{
    // Add to XML document node
    echo '<marker ';
    echo 'id="' . $row['id'] . '" ';
    echo 'name="' . parseToXML($row['name']) . '" ';
    echo 'address="' . parseToXML($row['address']) . '" ';
    echo 'lat="' . $row['lat'] . '" ';
    echo 'lng="' . $row['lng'] . '" ';
    echo 'type="' . $row['type'] . '" ';
    echo '/>';
    $ind = $ind + 1;
}

// End XML file
echo '</markers>';

?>
```

And here is the HTML page to display the map with markers. http://www.desemdelen.nl/mapview.html. I only changed the link to my XLM.php file and added my API code in the bottom. Map is loading, but no markers.

```
<!DOCTYPE html >
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
    <title>Using MySQL and PHP with Google Maps</title>
    <style>
      /* Always set the map height explicitly to define the size of the div
       * element that contains the map. */
      #map {
        height: 100%;
      }
      /* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */
      html, body {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }
    </style>
  </head>

<html>
  <body>
    <div id="map"></div>

    <script>
      var customLabel = {
        restaurant: {
          label: 'R'
        },
        bar: {
          label: 'B'
        }
      };

        function initMap() {
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          center: new google.maps.LatLng(-33.863276, 151.207977),
          zoom: 12
        });
        var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow;

          // Change this depending on the name of your PHP or XML file
          downloadUrl('http://www.desemdelen.nl/XML.php', function(data) {
            var xml = data.responseXML;
            var markers = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName('marker');
            Array.prototype.forEach.call(markers, function(markerElem) {
              var id = markerElem.getAttribute('id');
              var name = markerElem.getAttribute('name');
              var address = markerElem.getAttribute('address');
              var type = markerElem.getAttribute('type');
              var point = new google.maps.LatLng(
                  parseFloat(markerElem.getAttribute('lat')),
                  parseFloat(markerElem.getAttribute('lng')));

              var infowincontent = document.createElement('div');
              var strong = document.createElement('strong');
              strong.textContent = name
              infowincontent.appendChild(strong);
              infowincontent.appendChild(document.createElement('br'));

              var text = document.createElement('text');
              text.textContent = address
              infowincontent.appendChild(text);
              var icon = customLabel[type] || {};
              var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                map: map,
                position: point,
                label: icon.label
              });
              marker.addListener('click', function() {
                infoWindow.setContent(infowincontent);
                infoWindow.open(map, marker);
              });
            });
          });
        }



      function downloadUrl(url, callback) {
        var request = window.ActiveXObject ?
            new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP') :
            new XMLHttpRequest;

        request.onreadystatechange = function() {
          if (request.readyState == 4) {
            request.onreadystatechange = doNothing;
            callback(request, request.status);
          }
        };

        request.open('GET', url, true);
        request.send(null);
      }

      function doNothing() {}
    </script>
    <script async defer
    src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=MY_API_KEY&callback=initMap">
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Strangly enough I can see the markers on an old laptop I am using, but not on any more recent devise. Where did I go wrong? Am I working with older versions perhaps (V1, V2,V3). Thank you!!

Comment: Your map works now.

Comment: check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1676688/mysql-connection-not-working-2002-no-such-file-or-directory

Comment: I've removed your API key from your question. Please don't share private API keys on public sites, and make sure you restrict them as per https://developers.google.com/maps/api-key-best-practices#restrict_apikey