# How can I make migration work after MAMP Update and Symfony 4 installation?

Tags: mysql, symfony, migration, mamp

I updated my Mamp Pro application to 6.2 and everything works well. My Symfony is running with the database, so everything is fine.

in the env file I am using this setting:

```
DATABASE_URL=mysql://root:root@localhost/mypage
```

Now the problem is, that in the console I want to make a migration, and this is not working anymore

```
php bin/console doctrine:migrations:diff
```

I get the error

> An exception occurred in driver: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file
> or directory

Comment: sometime removing the cache may help `sudo rm -rf var/cache/*` from projectDir

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MySQL connection not working: 2002 No such file or directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1676688/mysql-connection-not-working-2002-no-such-file-or-directory)

Comment: @yivi no unfortunately not, I already tried the solutions on the page, but they do not work for me. I am totally desperate. I do not understand

Comment: @johnSmith tested it, but it does not help

Comment: Kinda stupid question, but are you sure your mysql server is running? Can you connect via cli tool (`mysql -uroot -proot mypage`)?

Comment: Please share more details - if Symfony is running fine, but generating migrations does not work, what's the difference in configuration?

Comment: @NicoHaase Where can I check this difference. I made the sql settings in the .env file

Comment: @dbrumann the mysql server is running, my Symfony application is working, everything is fine, I can login and everything. The only thing is, that I cannot make any migrations in the console

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a long research I finally found the solution:

*The php version of the terminal did not match the php version of MAMP. I had to use the mamp php version instead of the default osx php version.*

**1. Locate your osx php version with:**

which php

**The result should be:**

/usr/local/bin/php

**2. Backup (move) your original php binary:**

sudo mv /usr/local/bin/php /usr/local/bin/php.bak

**3. Create the symlink:**

sudo ln -s /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.4.12/bin/php /usr/local/bin/php

**4. Run your new php version:**

php -v