# No such file or directory

Tags: php, mysqli, mariadb

I have a php script which start a simple mysqli connection to a mariaDB database:

```
$db = @new mysqli( $mysql_host, $mysql_user, $mysql_pw, $mysql_db ); 
if (!$db->connect_error) {
    $db->set_charset("utf8");
} else {
    echo $db->connect_error;
    exit;
}
```

This works, but sometimes I get the following $db->connect_error:

```
No such file or directory
```

One minute later it works again.
What does this mean? How can I fix this?

Comment: I think here is the answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/1676741/3231397

Comment: If this setting is wrong, I should not be able to get a connection. But I get a connection with somethimes this error.

Comment: what about this https://stackoverflow.com/a/6959675/3231397