# SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory when testing a post request in Postman | Laravel + MySQL

Tags: mysql, laravel

I'm trying to make an auth api, but when I try to register a user this error appears in Postman:

> Illuminate\Database\QueryException: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory (SQL: insert into `users` (`name`, `email`, `password`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (NomeTeste, teste, $2y$10$UwJfYrG2ugyAKVW1Hvjq7O1k51qfHYuF6F9abt56bg6Wrw7tEALIS, 2022-07-07 08:07:17, 2022-07-07 08:07:17)) in file /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php on line 759

I tried changing my DB_HOST beetween localhost and 127.0.0.1, but when is 127.0.0.1 the error is **"Connection Refused"**, and when is localhost the error is **"No such file or directory"** and the migrate gives this error:

> SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory (SQL: select * from
> information_schema.tables where table_schema = pontotel_cadastro and
> table_name = migrations and table_type = 'BASE TABLE')

I tried a lot of solutions that I found on the internet, but none of them helped me

Comment: check your MySQL status, is it running or not

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MySQL connection not working: 2002 No such file or directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1676688/mysql-connection-not-working-2002-no-such-file-or-directory)

Comment: Did you try running this on a vanilla Laravel install? Seems like your `migration` table is not even there.