# how do i connect to DB of wordpress in my "index.php" which i need to place out of the "wp-content" folder

Tags: php, wordpress

I have used the mysql_connect() to connect to the wordpress DB but am getting the error as...

```
/** The name of the database for WordPress */

define('DB_NAME', '---my DB name---');



/** MySQL database username */

define('DB_USER', '---my user name----');



/** MySQL database password */

define('DB_PASSWORD', '---my password---');



/** MySQL hostname */

define('DB_HOST', '----host name----');

mysql_connect(DB_HOST,DB_USER,DBPASSWORD,DB_NAME);
```

> Error: Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket
>   '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock'

Comment: Yeah well...without any code or something to look at, we can't really tell you anything. Maybe [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4448467/cant-connect-to-local-mysql-server-through-socket-var-lib-mysql-mysql-sock) could help you. An on another note: Please do not use `mysql_*` functions. They are deprecated and have been replaced with [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) and/or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli).

Comment: Sorry....I thought you wanted to reuse any of the Wordpress code, but apparently you only try to connect to the same database. As I mentioned above, have a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4448467/cant-connect-to-local-mysql-server-through-socket-var-lib-mysql-mysql-sock) and please don't use `mysql_*` functions.

Comment: Thanks for reply @Till Helge Helwig
But Please tell me what will i do now... if i want to connect to DB... am new to wordpress...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
require_once(path/to/wp-config.php');
mysql_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD);
```

Comment: yup...
am getting this error...
`Warning: require_once(path/to/wp-config.php) [function.require-once]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory `
will tring to solve it

Comment: if you are using in root folder then use require_once('wp-config.php');

Comment: Thanks budy.. 
it just required th correct path to wp-config.php file

Answer (score 0):

The key to using WordPress outside of WordPress is include the wp-load.php

```
// Include the wp-load'er
require_once("/path/to/wordpress/wp-load.php");
```

now you can use all the functions of wordpress in your php script

One problem with that solution is that it loads ALL the overhead of WordPress,

another way is as below

```
require_once( $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/wp-config.php' );
require_once( $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/wp-includes/wp-db.php' );
$wpdb = new wpdb( DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME, DB_HOST);
```

Comment: `wp-admin //folder
wp-content //folder
wp-includes //folder
wp-config.php // is the config file...
myfile.php // where i want an connection to wordpress DB`

Comment: check here http://frankiejarrett.com/2012/04/the-simplest-way-to-require-include-wp-load-php/