# blank page when login in

Tags: php, mysql, linux, fedora

i have code for sign in to my site
but when i sign in with username and password i get blank page
i am use linux server - fedora-
i am create database and import tables from terminal

this is my page form

```
<html>
<head>
<body background="se16.jpg">
<form method="post" action="w.php">
<center>
<br>
<h1> <p style="color:brown;">  Login Page </p> </h1> 

<hr color="brown"> <br> 
<caption><h1><p style="color:black;">please Enter Username & Password</p></h1><caption>
<table border="3">

<tr><td><h2><p style="color:black;">Username: </p></td><td><input type="text" name="username" /></td><h2></tr>

<tr><td><h2><p style="color:black;">Password:</p> </td><td><input type="password"     name="password" /></td></h2></tr>


<tr><td></td><td><input type="submit" value="Log in" /></td></tr>

</table>
</center>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

and php page for query is

```
<?php
session_start();
 echo "username: " . $_POST['username'];
 echo "<br>";
 echo "Password: " . $_POST['password'];
 echo "<br>";
include("connect.php");

// Pass Query
$query="SELECT username AND password FROM login ";

// Execute Query
$result = mysql_query($query) or die ("error in query:$query.".mysql_query());
echo $result;
echo "<br>";
$username=$_POST['username']; 
$password=$_POST['password'];

if(mysql_num_rows($result)>0)
{
echo "ssss";
 while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
 {
    $sql="SELECT * FROM login WHERE username='$username' AND password='$password'";
    $result=mysql_query($sql) or die ("error in query:$query.".mysql_query());
    $count=mysql_num_rows($result);

if($count == 1)
{
$query1="SELECT username FROM login WHERE password='$password'";
$result = mysql_query($query1)or die ("error in query:$query.".mysql_query());
while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
 {
  $username=$row['username'];
 }
 $flag=true;
 break;
 }
 }
}
else
    {
        echo 'No Data Found';
   }

  if($flag==true)
 {
    $data = mysql_fetch_object(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM login WHERE username='$username' AND password='$password'"));
$_SESSION['valid_user'] = $data->id;
    echo '<div align="left"><font color="#6666CC"> Welcome </font><font color="#FF6600">'.$username.'</font></div>';
echo '<div align="right"><a href="logout.php">Log Out</a></div>';
include("main1.php");
   }
  else
 {
include("log1.html");
  }

    // mysql_close($con);
  ?>
```

if i am use this code

```
     echo "username: " . $_POST['username'];
     echo "<br>";
     echo "Password: " . $_POST['password'];
     echo "<br>";
```

i get the username and password coorect

and connect .php file is

```
<?php
$host      ="localhost";
$username  ="root";
$password  ="MyS12345";
$db_name   ="jointdb";
$conn = mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect"); 
mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");

?>
```

Comment: check errors in terminal to execute the CMD- `sudo tail -f /var/log/httpd/error_log`

Comment: @KrishR i have this error [error] [client 127.0.0.1] PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected T_STRING in /var/www/html/projectsite/connect.php on line 4, referer: http://localhost/projectsite/index.html

Comment: Post your connect.php file code!

Comment: @KrishR <?php

$host      ="localhost;
$username  ="root";
$password  ="MyS12345";
$db_name   ="jointdb";
$conn = mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect"); 
mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");

?>

Comment: [Don't use `mysql_*`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php?rq=1); the `mysql_*` functions are outdated, [deprecated](http://us3.php.net/manual/en/intro.mysql.php), and insecure. Use [`MySQLi`](http://us3.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [`PDO`](http://us3.php.net/manual/en/intro.pdo.php) instead. Also, you are wide open to SQL injection.

Comment: @AbhikChakraborty after i update with ypur code. i get- Warning: mysql_connect(): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' (13) in /var/www/html/projectsite/connect.php on line 6 cannot connect

Comment: in connect.php, `$host ="localhost";`  You have missed to add to `"`

Comment: Two things to resolve the issue use $host = '127.0.0.1' or /etc/my.cnf  check [client]

socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock if its correct

Comment: check here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4448467/cant-connect-to-local-mysql-server-through-socket-var-lib-mysql-mysql-sock

Comment: @KrishR if i am use $host ="localhost.localdomain"; with selinux its ok. why

Answer (score 0):

First thing query is not correct

```
$query="SELECT username AND password FROM login ";
```

should be as

```
$query="SELECT username,password FROM login ";
```

In the connect.php the correct code is

```
$host ="localhost"; 
$username ="root"; 
$password ="MyS12345"; 
$db_name ="jointdb"; 
$conn = mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect"); mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");
```

NOTE : mysql_* functions are deprecated, so start learning mysqli_* functions or PDO.

Comment: thanks but the problem is still , i am use same project in windows server2008 without any problem

Comment: Add this 2 lines on the top of your script error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');  This will tell you more about errors.

Comment: after i added it i have Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING in /var/www/html/projectsite/connect.php on line 4 and the line 4 in connect.php is $username  ="root";

Comment: Ok can you post the first few lines og connect.php by editing the question?

Comment: Chakaraborty if i am use $host ="localhost.localdomain"; with selinux its ok. why

Comment: f i am use $host ="localhost.localdomain"; with selinux its ok. why

Comment: there are lot of things that are there in mysql u need to check the HOST and DB table in mysql that might answer