# MySQL root error

Tags: mysql, centos5

I am a newbie in LAMP administration. I have tried a few times installing mysql. Currently, i have MySQL 5.0 installed in my CentOS 5.5 desktop.After changing the MySQL versions a few times, i still got the error.

I am always stuck with these 2 errors here:

```
Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' (2)    
Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
```

Whenever i managed to solve either 1, another 1 error would occur.

These are my link reference:
[Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' (2)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4448467/cant-connect-to-local-mysql-server-through-socket-var-lib-mysql-mysql-sock)

http://www.webhostingtalk.com/showthread.php?t=875255

I also have already tried to reset the root password.

And whenever i logged in the mysql through:

```
mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables &,
```

i will always end up with:

```
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
Rows matched: 0  Changed: 0  Warnings: 0
```

Can anyone help me solve this please?

Comment: Try to post on [serverfault](http://serverfault.com/) instead

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that you have started mysql server

```
    service mysqld start
```

by root permission

Comment: Since the error message clearly mentions `Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)` it implies that the server is running, they need to provide a valid password

Comment: @Hanky웃Panky ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' (2) this occurs when service is stoped

Comment: everytime i tried to access mysql, i did start the mysqld. and, i have never set any password for root yet actually. the reason why am confused i cannot access without password.