# Can't connect to MySql using PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I have the same issues described here: [Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' (2)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4448467/cant-connect-to-local-mysql-server-through-socket-var-lib-mysql-mysql-sock)

but, I am certain my credentials are in correctly.

I am using a hosting company and ( tsohosts.co.uk ) and assume that MySql starts automatically.

I'm not sure what to check next. Is there any way to get more details about the "or die" phrase.

Here is my code:

```
$dbc = mysqli_connect("localhost","CorrectUser","CorrectPass",CorrectDB") 
or die ('No can do');

$query = "INSERT INTO users(firstName,lastName,username,password,email,dateJoin,school,level) " 
." VALUES ('value','value','value','value','value', NOW(),'value','Not yet set')";

mysqli_query($dbc, $query) or die ("I couldn't get it in!"); 

mysqli_close($dbc);
?>
```

and the error is

```
Warning: mysqli_connect() [function.mysqli-connect]: (HY000/2002): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' (2) in ../testdb.php on line 16
No can do
```

Do I have to do something else start MySQL within the PHP script?

Comment: If you are using a hosting company, then it's unlikely the server address will be localhost, check with them for the correct address.

Comment: Thanks for reading - yes this is what it turned out to be. Fixed.

Comment: The Blue Dog is correct. With tsohost, the mysql server is on a different address and this will most likely vary account to account, you should be able to check the support article.

Answer (score 0):

You missed a double quote in `$dbc` try this

```
$dbc = mysqli_connect("localhost","CorrectUser","CorrectPass","CorrectDB") 
or die ('No can do');
```

You put a double quote and a fullstop at the wrong place in `$query` it should be like this

```
$query = "INSERT INTO users(firstName,lastName,username,password,email,dateJoin,school,level)
 VALUES ('value','value','value','value','value', NOW(),'value','Not yet set')";
```

Also remove `$dbc` from the `mysqli_query()` function and also escape the single quote in the `die()` function like so:

```
mysqli_query($query) or die ("I couldn't get it in!");
```

Comment: `mysqli_error()` and not `mysql_error()` --- `mysqli_*` and `mysql_*` fucntion do not mix; ***ever.*** Plus, no need to escape single quotes inside double quotes. Change `"I couldn\'t get it in!"` to `"I couldn't get it in!"`