# Error: Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (2) in Ubuntu

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, sockets

I tried to run rake db:setup, but I got this error.
I want to my mysql socket be in this path (/tmp/mysql.sock), but I think it is not..
How can I change the socket path?

I'm using Ubuntu

Comment: The socket's path is defined in `/etc/mysql/my.cnf`. Ubuntu's default socket location is probably `/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock` and you should change your Rails configuration (in database.yml) to point at the MySQL socket at that location rather than change MySQL to use a different socket path.

Comment: I want to change MySQL to use a different socket path because I'm running a Rails project by the company I work. And they configure to use tmp/mysql.sock

Comment: Okay then, fair enough. Change it in `/etc/mysql/my.cnf` to your desired path and restart the mysql service `sudo service mysql restart`.

Comment: You could also create a symlink to your desired socket location, which would avoid having to modify your daemon config http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4448467/cant-connect-to-local-mysql-server-through-socket-var-lib-mysql-mysql-sock/21745101#21745101

Comment: Do you know how to edit system files in Ubuntu?  If you use Vim as your editor `sudo vim /etc/mysql/my.cnf` then restart the service.

Comment: Or if you don't know how to use vim/vi, use `nano` or whatever your text editor of choice is, but you will need admin privileges via `sudo` to do it.

Comment: I tried with nano. Just edit socket path. But it wouldn't work.

Comment: What wouldn't work? Did you change the socket path for both the `[server]` and `[client]` sections of my.cnf? Did you `sudo service mysql restart` afterward?