# Mysql connect externally but sock error locally

Tags: mysql

I can connect to my MySQL server externally (so I know the server is up and running) but when I try to connect locally I get the good old

```
 Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' (2)
```

So unlike other situations my server IS running - its just I can't connect locally?

Comment: Does the mentioned file actually exist?

Also see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4448467/cant-connect-to-local-mysql-server-through-socket-var-lib-mysql-mysql-sock

Comment: No but I can connect externally. Would an external connection not use the sock file?

Comment: No, that uses the TCP/IP socket - this is a Unix socket. A work-around is to connect to `127.0.0.1` instead I believe.

`On Unix, MySQL programs treat the host name localhost specially, in a way that is likely different from what you expect compared to other network-based programs. For connections to localhost, MySQL programs attempt to connect to the local server by using a Unix socket file.` https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/connecting.html

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are not maintaining mysql.sock which is a must for local connections. You should first check mysql.sock file exists or not at your mentioned location i.e. /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock. If not, add below in your my.conf file and restart mysql server

```
[mysqld]
socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock

[client]
socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
```

Comment: If it doesn't exist, adding paths to it won't help. You can either set the paths correctly to the actual location or symlink it from the actual location to `/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock` with `ln -s`

Comment: Sorry Philip I'm not understanding you properly. How will symlinking help for a file that doesn't exist? Do I still need to restart the server as well?

Comment: You need to find the mysql.sock file and either add lines similar to those posted but with the correct path OR create a symlink from the correct path to /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock. Both the server and client need to use the same file. The file basically acts as a pipe to transmit information - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_file_types#Socket

Answer (score 0):

You may be missing `mysql-client`.

Your server may be running fine, but you still need a client in order to run locally.

To fix this on Unix/Linux, use your favorite/default dependency management service to install `mysql-client`. Windows installs generally do this automatically, as do Mac installs from the MySQL website.

#### Examples

Debian/Ubuntu:

```
sudo apt-get install mysql-client
```

RedHat:

```
sudo yum install mysql-client
```