# mysql is not running properly when rails server runs. in vagrant envirnement

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

> Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' (2) (Mysql::Error)

when i run rails server it gives me above error. I am using rails 2.3

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' (2)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4448467/cant-connect-to-local-mysql-server-through-socket-var-lib-mysql-mysql-sock)

Comment: but the solution there is not proper . because this issue arises when mysql not runing in background. so http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4448467/cant-connect-to-local-mysql-server-through-socket-var-lib-mysql-mysql-sock is not proper solution

Comment: I see.  Could you update your question to explain the differences, it would help future users.

Answer (score 0):

I have used this command to run the sql server

```
sudo /sbin/service mysql-default start
```