# bind-address not present in my.cnf file - Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, artisan-migrate

While running this command '`php artisan migrate`', i got this error "`couldn't connect to local MYSQL server through socket`".
[image]

I was going through all stackoverflow answers, i got many suggestions saying 'change bind-address:localhost to 127.0.0.1'.

I entered this command '`find / -name my.cnf`' and got two locations of 'my.cnf' file.

- /opt/lampp/etc/my.cnf
- /etc/mysql/my.cnf

I've confusion.. Which file i've to edit. Which one is correct path ?

And, in my "my.cnf" file, no 'bind-address' is present.
If i write manually, so where to write "bind-address" in my.cnf file ? Or, anywhere i can write in that file.?

Here is 'my.cnf' file

```
# The following options will be passed to all MySQL clients
[client]
#password   = your_password
port        = 3306
socket      = /opt/lampp/var/mysql/mysql.sock

# Here follows entries for some specific programs

# The MySQL server
[mysqld]
user = mysql
port=3306
socket      = /opt/lampp/var/mysql/mysql.sock
skip-external-locking
key_buffer = 16M
max_allowed_packet = 1M
table_open_cache = 64
sort_buffer_size = 512K
net_buffer_length = 8K
read_buffer_size = 256K
read_rnd_buffer_size = 512K
myisam_sort_buffer_size = 8M

# Where do all the plugins live
plugin_dir = /opt/lampp/lib/mysql/plugin/
```

Please Help Me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made changes in `"Project-Folder-Name/config/database.php"`. And, it worked.
Added `'unix_socket'   => '/opt/lampp/var/mysql/mysql.sock',`

```
'mysql' => [
            'driver'    => 'mysql',
            'host'      => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
            'database'  => env('DB_DATABASE', 'DatabaseName'),
            'username'  => env('DB_USERNAME', 'root'),
            'password'  => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
        'unix_socket'   => '/opt/lampp/var/mysql/mysql.sock', //Your sock got from above
            'charset'   => 'utf8',
            'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
            'prefix'    => '',
            'strict'    => false,
        ],
```

Answer (score 0):

verify your mysql service is running..try to

```
mysql service start or mysql service restart
```

Or you can checkout some of the suggestion given here [Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' (2)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4448467/cant-connect-to-local-mysql-server-through-socket-var-lib-mysql-mysql-sock)

Comment: Yeah, My MySql Service Running Very Fine

Comment: for the bind-address, you can add it below myisam_sort_buffer_size and stop and start mysql service when doing the change.

Comment: Yes. I did. But, same issue. Any idea, how to rectify it.