# Could not connect to local MySQL server with Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, ubuntu, laravel-5, artisan-migrate

When I run this command `find / -name my.cnf` I find two locations for `my.cnf`

- `/opt/lampp/etc/my.cnf`
- `/etc/mysql/my.cnf`

I don't get which one is used by MySQL server?

And, when i run command `php artisan migrate` , I get this error

```
 [PDOException]                                                              
  SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket ' 
  /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)
```

You can all see very clearly the error path showing `/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock` (Actually, in my system/desktop. There is no folder name "mysqld" inside "run folder")

```
I have a `mysql.sock` file inside /opt/lampp/var/mysql/mysql.sock
```

So, what can be the issue. ?? Please help. 
I asked the question here [bind-address not present in my.cnf file - Laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32437796/bind-address-not-present-in-my-cnf-file-laravel/) 3 hours before, but no response until now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all,

- Find your **php.ini** file in your system using `$ php -i |grep php\.ini` command OR click [where can I find the php.ini for php-cli](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3057110/where-can-i-find-the-php-ini-for-php-cli).
- Open **php.ini** file.
- And, make sure these lines are present or not.

  a) `extension=mysql.so`  b)`extension=pdo_mysql.so`
- If Yes, remove (;) this before them.
- If not present, run this command `sudo apt-get install php5-mysql`

Now, type `php artisan migrate` command. I'm sure you will get **error**

> can't connect to local MYSQL server through socket

Now,

- Change bind-address from `localhost` to `127.0.0.1`
- Run `/opt/lampp/bin/php`.
- After running this if you get

> "unable to load dynamic library"

Then, remove `php_mssql.dll extension` (for non-windows)

- If not getting error, come directly to **Project-Name-Folder/config/database.php** file and add this code `'unix_socket'   => '/opt/lampp/var/mysql/mysql.sock'`,

Find the complete path of `mysql.sock`, and add it

```
'mysql' => [
    'driver'    => 'mysql',
    'host'      => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
    'database'  => env('DB_DATABASE', 'danishLara'),
    'username'  => env('DB_USERNAME', 'root'),
    'password'  => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
    'unix_socket'   => '/opt/lampp/var/mysql/mysql.sock', //Add this line here
    'charset'   => 'utf8',
    'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
    'prefix'    => '',
    'strict'    => false,
],
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to uninstall lamp , it's better to use a manual configuration install mysql and apache2 manualy don't use lamp !

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that MySQL is running first (simple, but good to check!), and make sure that the correct install of MySQL is being run (if you have a LAMP install as well as a standalone MySQL install).

If you are connecting using `localhost`, try connecting using `127.0.0.1`. This may use a TCP/IP connector instead of the socket - just a workaround.