# laravel cant connect to mysql database on VM LAMP

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel-5.1

hey guys im trying to learn laravel and im following the tutorail but i cant seem to connect to my database via VM running LAMP. I've looked thru every single post and nothing is still working

when i go run the command `php artisan migrate` i get the following error

`[PDOException]

  SQLSTATE[HY000] [2003] Can't connect to MySQL server on '10.0.1.22' (111)`

i even followed this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32440938/could-not-connect-to-local-mysql-server-laravel) and got the following error

`[PDOException]

  SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/opt/lampp/var/mysql/mysql.sock' (2)`

my laravel app is running on port `8000` but my phpmyadmin is at `10.0.1.22/phpmyadmin` im not sure if that could be the issue, im still a beginner so my debugging solutions are limited.

Here are my `database.php` file and my `.envi` file

database.php

```
        'mysql' => [
            'driver'    => 'mysql',
            'host'      => env('DB_HOST', '10.0.1.22'),
            'database'  => env('DB_DATABASE', 'task'),
            'username'  => env('DB_USERNAME', 'root'),
            'password'  => env('DB_PASSWORD', 'test'),
            'charset'   => 'utf8',
            'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
            'prefix'    => '',
            'strict'    => false,
        ],
```

and my .envi file

```
APP_ENV=local
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_KEY=HBzhX830sIrNbZ2hdB23DGAuGa4mj4IL

DB_HOST=10.0.1.22
DB_DATABASE=task
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=test

CACHE_DRIVER=file
SESSION_DRIVER=file
QUEUE_DRIVER=sync

MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=mailtrap.io
MAIL_PORT=2525
MAIL_USERNAME=null
MAIL_PASSWORD=null
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null
```

thanks for all the help

Comment: Have you tried putting 127.0.0.1 as DB_HOST?

Comment: @MagnusEriksson WTH?? That worked!!! but how??? can you please explain

Comment: 10.0.1.22 is the external address to your VM machine from your computer. Since Apache/PHP and MySQL are running on the same machine, you shouldn't try to connect them with the external address but rather with the internal (127.0.0.1). The MySQL root user probably only accept calls from 127.0.0.1 as well. (it's a setting when you create a user in MySQL)

Comment: @MagnusEriksson thank u for this

Comment: I'll add it as an answer so you can check it as solved. :)

Comment: I've added the solution, and explaination, as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the DB_HOST to 127.0.0.1

10.0.1.22 is the external address to your VM machine from your computer.
Since Apache/PHP and MySQL are running on the same machine, there's no reason connect them with the external address but rather with the internal (127.0.0.1).

When you create a user in MySQL you can set what IP'addresses it should accept connections from and as default, in most cases, the root user is usually set to only listen to internal calls (127.0.0.1).

Answer (score 0):

Change your

```
DB_HOST=10.0.1.22
```

to

```
DB_HOST = 127.0.0.1
```

> **Because Loaclhost define on this port.** Simply it means `127.0.0.1 == localhost`

[`$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host']`](http://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/latest/config.html#cfg_Servers_host)