# 2002 Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, lampp

I have installed lampp on a centos server that mysql server has been installed on. I removed mysql and I can access databases by this command on server:

```
/opt/lampp/bin/mysql -u username -p
```

When I want to access a database on this server by PDO in a php file, I receive this error:

```
 [2002] Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' (2)
```

I also removed `var/lib/mysql` directory.
What is the solution?

Comment: @C0dekid.php I got this error before removing this directory.

Comment: another solution would be: instead of using `localhost` use `127.0.0.1`. See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4448467/cant-connect-to-local-mysql-server-through-socket-var-lib-mysql-mysql-sock

Comment: After deleting the folder this will be next to impossible to diagnose. Could have been a selinux issue. Using TCP instead of sockets, as suggested, will solve the problem but will reduce performance (not much, but you should be aware of it).

Comment: @C0dekid.php thanks a lot , it worked ;)