# Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock

Tags: mysql

So this is the first time using mySQL.  I recently installed mySQL server a few hours ago and XAMPP a few days ago, although only launched XAMPP for the first time today. I'm not sure I need both do I? I can run the server from either mysql or XAMPP.

I'm trying to connect to the database via bluehost (webdomain) using phpmyadmin.

I have the mySQL server running but still get the error 
`Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock` .  I tried to locate the file inside /var/lib/ but only see a postfix folder inside, not mySQL.

If somehow I need to put the file there, how do I do so?

EDIT: I ran `netstat -ln | grep -o -m 1 -E '\S*mysqld?\.sock'` in terminal while mysql is running and this come up: `/tmp/mysql.sock`.  I believe this is where the file is and I need to move it somehow.

EDIT2: I opened up my.cnf file and changed the socket to `/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock` and then run the server from XAMPP.  when I do `netstat -ln | grep -o -m 1 -E '\S*mysqld?\.sock'` in terminal now it comes back with `/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock`.  Nevertheless, the problem still occurs.

Comment: Try looking at these : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4448467/cant-connect-to-local-mysql-server-through-socket-var-lib-mysql-mysql-sock or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5376427/cant-connect-to-local-mysql-server-through-socket-var-mysql-mysql-sock-38 or http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/98467/how-to-solve-cant-connect-to-local-mysql-server-through-socket-error

Comment: Ensure that your mysql service is running ?

Comment: yes it is running.

Answer (score 0):

So, you should change your mysql.default_socket in php.ini to /tmp/mysql.sock and restart your web server.

Comment: Went into php.ini and changed the line `pdo_mysql.default_socket=/tmp/mysql.sock` - didn't do anything

Comment: Please also check all places in php.ini where mysql socket is set to /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock and change these to /tmp/mysql.sock Make sure your MySQL also has socket variable set to /tmp/mysql.sock. Restart both MySQL & web server services

Comment: when i command f to try find whats been set to there i find nothing.  above setting the socket it states `Default socket name for local MySQL connects.  If empty, uses the built-in MySQL defaults.` I have changed the socket for pdo_mysql, mysql and mysqli.

Comment: Could you check for the value of socket variable in MySQL? mysql> show variables like '%socket%';

Comment: it this done in terminal or? I only have mySQL server installed

Comment: It does not matter how. I'm using mysql client program in terminal but you can use phpMyAdmin or any other program which allows you to run SQL queries e.g. MySQL Workbench