# Use Sqoop to import data from mysql to Hadoop but fail

Tags: mysql, hadoop

I tried to import data through Sqoop using the following command.

```
sqoop import -connect jdbc:mysql://localhost/test_sqoop --username root --table test
```

but I got the **connection refuse error.**

And I found out I can't connect to mysql and got this error:

```
Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock'
```

And I also found out if I don't execute `start-dfs.sh`,`mysql.sock` exists in `/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock`.

[mysql](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OEHKB.jpg)

After I executed `start-dfs.sh`,`mysql.sock` would be gone and I can't connect to mysql.

[start-dfs.sh](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c4ogd.jpg)

Below is /etc/my.cnf configuration.

datadir=/var/lib/mysql
socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock

Comment: Could you please share the content of your `/etc/my.cnf` file? There should be a section called [client] with something like this `socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock`. Can you execute this command? `mysql.server start`

Comment: My /etc/cnf has configured socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock but not in the section [client] but [mysqld].And when I execute the command mysql.server start,it shows 'command not found' error.

Comment: I think that your MySQL is not running, have you tried to do some of these answers to the same problem? 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4448467/cant-connect-to-local-mysql-server-through-socket-var-lib-mysql-mysql-sock

Maybe it's just a matter of permissions or something very simple to fix.

Answer (score 0):

- jdbc string should be: `jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test_sqoop`, best practice is to use server name intesad of `localhost` or `127.0.0.1`. you can get the server name from this command `hostname -f`. so jdbc string should be `jdbc:mysql://servername:3306/test_sqoop` - replace the server name by out put of `hostname -f` command.
- you need `-P` or `--password` or `--connection-param-file` to pass the password to the `sqoop` command. `sqoop` doesn't read from `.my.cnf` file. - see usage [here](https://sqoop.apache.org/docs/1.4.1-incubating/SqoopUserGuide.html#_syntax)