# php - mysql database connection

Tags: php, mysql, database

I'm trying to connect to my database to retrieve the table from sql workbench, but when I do it comes up with the following error message

> could not connect to MySQL Unknown MySQL server host "Guada"

The php script is as follows:

```
<?php

//Using details to establish database connection
DEFINE ('DB_USER', 'i7421760');
DEFINE ('DB PASSWORD', '*********');
DEFINE ('DB_HOST', 'guada');
DEFINE ('DB_NAME', 'i7421760');




$dbc = @mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME)
OR die('could not connect to MySQL ' .
        mysqli_connect_error());
/*
If the connection couldn't be established it 
will print a display message and the error report
*/
?>
```

If it is the case of just getting the host name wrong, where can I find it? The table I want to retrieve is on sql workbench.

Any help is appreciated 
thanks in advance

Comment: Usually host is `localhost` or `127.0.0.1`

Comment: NOTE: SQL Workbench is a tool used to simplify MYSQL database management **not a database** MYSQL is the DBMS

Comment: So, you got `Unknown MySQL server host "Guada"'` - why do you think that is?

Answer (score 1):

Update your code:

```
//Using details to establish database connection
DEFINE ('DB_USER', 'i7421760');
DEFINE ('DB PASSWORD', '*********');
DEFINE ('DB_HOST', 'localhost');
DEFINE ('DB_NAME', 'i7421760');




$dbc = @mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME)
OR die('could not connect to MySQL ' .
        mysqli_connect_error());
/*
If the connection couldn't be established it 
will print a display message and the error report
```

Comment: When I change the host to local host, I get the following error message: could not connect to MySQL Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' (2)

Comment: Please check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4448467/cant-connect-to-local-mysql-server-through-socket-var-lib-mysql-mysql-sock

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible your php and MySQL both run on a hosting service somewhere?

Many hosting services configure their internal networks so MySQL can be reached from php running on their internal servers, but not  directly from customers' machines outside the hosting service networks. If you must access your MySQL directly from your home or office, ask your hosting service tech support for help.

But keep in mind that you're running a security risk by opening up your MySQL database to access by the broader internet.

Comment: Yeah the host is elsewhere, I'm using my home laptop so that could be the problem there. I'll get in touch with the host to try resolve the issue. Thank you