# CRON Job To Reset mySQL DB Each Hour

Tags: mysql

I have a mysql database that is meant to be used on a "demo" website. I need this to be restored or reset each hour.

I have have tried two methods to accomplish this and tried each method several ways (from what I read, either method should work as good as the other).

I am using a VPS on Dreamhost.

Here is what my CRON job looks like:

```
mysql -h my_db_host -u my_username -pmy_password my_db_name < /home/usr/scripts/simplecrud.sql
```

Error that I am getting each time the job runs is

```
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)
```

How can I fix this ... what am I missing?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' (2)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4448467/cant-connect-to-local-mysql-server-through-socket-var-lib-mysql-mysql-sock)

Answer (score 0):

if the host is localhost, if yes try 127.0.0.1 instead

if this is also not working, try to check if the host from where you connect is allowed to connect (under the user)

Comment: I am not using localhost but the actual address

Comment: check if the given user has the permission to access from the given address

Comment: If you use phpmyadmin, you will see it under user management what hosts are allowed. Your host from which you connect has to be there for the user

Comment: User (me) has permission to access db (its my db and runs on my server ... the same server where the demo website).

Comment: so it is on localhost?
if so try both -h 127.0.0.1 and -h localhost

Comment: No, not localhost ... my hosting provider explicitly states to not use "localhost" when connecting to your database but to use the hard address.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155535/discussion-between-cilap-and-kulergary).