# mysql fail to connect eventhough it is started

Tags: mysql

Mysql failed to connect . can someone give me an idea how to solve it 
I did the following

```
[root@mysrver-01 ~]# sudo service mysql restart
cat: /vol/db1/mysql/mysrver-01.med.edu.pid: Input/output error
MySQL (Percona Server) server process # is not running!    [FAILED]
rm: cannot remove `/vol/db1/mysql/mysrver-01.med.edu.pid': Read-only file system
Starting MySQL (Percona Server)    
[root@mysrver-01 ~]# mysql -u root -p
Enter password: 
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' (2)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' (2)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4448467/cant-connect-to-local-mysql-server-through-socket-var-lib-mysql-mysql-sock)

Comment: This sounds like a OS-level or hardware problem. "IO error" and "Read-only file system" should not normally happen. I don't think this is a programming question hence off-topic.