# How to db:setup mysql2 database?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, database, ruby-on-rails-5, mysql2

I'm using mysql2 gem on rails 5. Also I use AWS Cloud9 EC2 instance for development if that helps.

Here is error I'm getting:

```
$ RAILS_ENV=development bundle exec rake db:setup 

rake aborted! 
Mysql2::Error::ConnectionError: 
Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/mysql/mysql.sock' (2)
```

Here is my database.yml file:

```
development:
  adapter: mysql2
  socket: /var/mysql/mysql.sock
  database: wagn_development
  username: user
  password: user
  host: localhost

test:
  adapter: mysql2
  socket: /var/mysql/mysql.sock
  database: wagn_test
  username: user
  password: user
  host: localhost

production:
  adapter: mysql2
  socket: /var/mysql/mysql.sock
  database: wagn_production
  username: user
  password: user
  host: localhost
```

How to solve the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this is not about Rails.

Are you using RDS or the DB is at same machine?

Have you read this or tryed any of thoses? I believe this is releated

[Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' (2)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4448467/cant-connect-to-local-mysql-server-through-socket-var-lib-mysql-mysql-sock)