# Getting an error while installing mysql-server on CentOS 8

Tags: mysql, mariadb, centos8

`Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' (2)`

Can someone please explain why I am getting this error and how to resolve it while installing `mysql-server` by doing `mysql_secure_installation` ?

Similarly, error occurs while installing `maridb-server`.

```
[root@servera-clone ~]# mysql_secure_installation 

NOTE: RUNNING ALL PARTS OF THIS SCRIPT IS RECOMMENDED FOR ALL MariaDB
      SERVERS IN PRODUCTION USE!  PLEASE READ EACH STEP CAREFULLY!

In order to log into MariaDB to secure it, we'll need the current
password for the root user.  If you've just installed MariaDB, and
you haven't set the root password yet, the password will be blank,
so you should just press enter here.

Enter current password for root (enter for none): 
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' (2)
Enter current password for root (enter for none):
```

Thanks

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4448467/cant-connect-to-local-mysql-server-through-socket-var-lib-mysql-mysql-sock

Comment: Thanks @HoneyboyWilson