# The server quit without updating PID file Is another mysql moving?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I made Rails's application, and when I run command `mysql.server start`,error happens

```
Starting MySQL
.....................[...]
ERROR! The server quit without updating PID file 
  (/usr/local/var/mysql/XXXnoMBP.pid).
```

When I tried to access to db in Sequel Pro,socket connection error happens like

```
MySQL response: Can't connect to local MySQL server
  through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (2)
```

When I run command of brew, it shows brew completely installed, also when I run `sudo mysql.server start`,same error happens.

By the way, when I run `ps -ef | grep mysql`, several things are showed. I think this means another mysql is moving, but is this right?

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/748478/cannot-find-mysql-sock) might help.

Comment: You might also try deleting the pid file