# SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory , how to solve?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Working with PDO Class I've got a problem with a PHP socket connection.

After searching, I looked at [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20723803/pdoexception-sqlstatehy000-2002-no-such-file-or-directory) and couldn't find any appropriate answer for me.

I using macOS Sierra Version 10.12.6

I tried to get some information from `mysql> show variables like '%sock%'` but didn't get any result from mysql shell. I logged successfully.

Don't have any `my.cnf` file in my `/etc` folder.

This is the result I got from `php -i | grep pdo`:

```
pdo_mysql.default_socket => /var/mysql/mysql.sock => /var/mysql/mysql.sock
```

I am not using Laravel.

I changed configuration in my `php.ini` file to `pdo_mysql.default_socket=/var/mysql/mysql.sock`, but it still does not work.

How can I connect PHP and MySQL working properly on same socket connection?

Comment: Look at `/etc/my.cnf`. In the `[mysqld]` section you can define a `socket=/var/mysql/mysql.sock` and restart the mysql service. The fact that `show variables like `'%sock%'` returned nothing suggests your mysqld may not be configured to open a local socket.  Alternatively you might be able to connect via TCP to `127.0.0.1` instead of specifying `localhost` (for which mysql will use a socket) for your database connection.

Comment: The second way i tried and i got the same result .. 
I can't find the /etc/my.cnf folder , in mine /etc folder on mac there is no such file 'my.cnf' . I do have the .cnf file in mine php /xamppfile/etc/my.cnf , do you mean file in that location ?

Comment: I found on mine XAMP/xamppfiles/etc/my.cnf [mysqld] section this configuration -> user = mysql port=3306
socket = /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/var/mysql/mysql.sock ..
Still not working  .. What can be the problem ?

Answer (score 0):

I'll tell you what I had to do on my Ubuntu. I am using LAMPP

Stop MYSQL system

```
sudo service mysql stop
```

Uninstall apache from the system

```
sudo apt remove apache2
```

run lampp

```
sudo /opt/lampp/manager-linux-x64.run
```

I did not change default servers.

stop all servers
click in Configure at MySQL Database
open Conf File

I had to find my socket adress [Cannot find mysql.sock](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/748478/cannot-find-mysql-sock)
/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock

Change the socket configuration

```
socket=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
```